# How to get the symbol name for a memory address in GDB?

Tags: debugging, memory, gdb

For instance, I know that 0x46767f0 belongs to an NSString*, is there any way I can find out what NSString it is to help me find some bugs I'm after?

Comment: Reverse question: [gdb - Find the exact address of variable Buf - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462915/find-the-exact-address-of-variable-buf) ■ To do in gdb Python API: [GDB Python API: Getting symbol name from address - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47916564/gdb-python-api-getting-symbol-name-from-address?noredirect=1&lq=1) ■ For local variables: [c++ - Why can't GDB find symbol from address with info symbol? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61507267/why-cant-gdb-find-symbol-from-address-with-info-symbol)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I believe you're looking for:

```
info symbol <addresss>
```

Print the name of a symbol which is stored at the address addr. If no symbol is stored exactly at addr, GDB prints the nearest symbol and an offset from it.

**Example:**

```
(gdb) info symbol 0x400225
_start + 5 in section .text of /tmp/a.out

(gdb) info symbol 0x2aaaac2811cf
__read_nocancel + 6 in section .text of /usr/lib64/libc.so.6
```

You can read more about it [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Symbols.html).

Comment: Remark: "nearest" here means "nearest before" (which is what you normally want anyway)

Answer (score 16):

gdb> list *0xAABBCCDD

That tells you the filename and line number.

Answer (score 6):

If it is a stack variable, there is no way that I am aware to do it. Otherwise, try `p/a <pointer symbol or address>` and it will print the symbol name (or offset to the nearest symbol name).

Answer (score 3):

po 0x46767f0

will send a `-description` message to the object. That will print out the contents of your NSString but I suggest using Brian's answer to check the contents of your address before you send random messages to random addresses.

Answer (score 3):

**`addr2line`**

This Binutils utility can handle any symbol address, including variables and function names.

It is non-interactive by default, which is useful in some cases, when doing post-mortems.

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int myvar;

int main(void) {
    printf("myvar = %d\n", myvar);
}
```

Compile and disassemble:

```
gcc -O 0 -g gdb3 -o main -pedantic-errors -std=c89 -Wextra main.c
readelf -s tmp.out  | grep -E ' (main|myvar)'
```

Gives:

```
55: 0000000000201014     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   24 myvar
65: 000000000000064a    32 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 main
```

And now we can try:

```
addr2line -e main 201014 64a
```

which gives:

```
/full/path/to/main.c:3
/full/path/to/main.c:5
```

Boost stack trace library uses it for example to show stack trace lines: [print call stack in C or C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899870/print-call-stack-in-c-or-c/54365144#54365144)