# How to print a stack trace whenever a certain function is called

Tags: c++, c, linux, stack-trace, callstack

Is there any way to dump the call stack in a running process in C or C++ every time a certain function is called?  What I have in mind is something like this:

```
void foo()
{
   print_stack_trace();

   // foo's body

   return
}
```

Where `print_stack_trace` works similarly to [`caller`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html) in Perl.

Or something like this:

```
int main (void)
{
    // will print out debug info every time foo() is called
    register_stack_trace_function(foo); 

    // etc...
}
```

where `register_stack_trace_function` puts some sort of internal breakpoint that will cause a stack trace to be printed whenever `foo` is called.

Does anything like this exist in some standard C library?

I am working on Linux, using GCC.

---

### Background

I have a test run that behaves differently based on some commandline switches that shouldn't affect this behavior.  My code has a pseudo-random number generator that I assume is being called differently based on these switches.  I want to be able to run the test with each set of switches and see if the random number generator is called differently for each one.

Comment: @Nathan: As far as I know, there is no STANDARD way to do so, however they may be libraries out there that can help you

Comment: Wouldn't this be either to achieve in a debugger?

Comment: @dmckee, it would indeed, except that the mismatch occurs after the function has been called a few thousand times, so doing it manually in a debugger is out of the question.  If only I had an intern... :-)

Comment: @Nathan: If your debugger is gdb it can [handle that case](http://blog.vinceliu.com/2009/07/gdbs-conditional-breakpoints.html).  I can't tell you about others, but I assume gdb is not alone in have this functionality.  **Aside:** I just *looked* at my earlier comment. ::gag:: `s/easier/either/` how the hell did that happen?

Comment: @dmckee: In fact, it should be `s/either/easier`.  What I would need to do with gdb is write a script that breaks on that function and prints out the stack trace, then continues.  Now that I think about it, maybe it's time for me to learn about gdb scripting.

Comment: C-only version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105659/how-can-one-grab-a-stack-trace-in-c

Comment: incoming https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/basic_stacktrace

Answer (score 103, accepted):

For a linux-only solution you can use [backtrace(3)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/backtrace.3.html) that simply returns an array of `void *` (in fact each of these point to the return address from the corresponding stack frame). To translate these to something of use, there's [backtrace_symbols(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/backtrace_symbols).

Pay attention to the [notes section in backtrace(3)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/backtrace.3.html#NOTES):

> The symbol names may be unavailable
>   without the use of special linker
>   options.
>          For systems using the GNU linker, it is necessary to use the
>   -rdynamic linker
>          option.  Note that names of "static" functions are not exposed,
>   and won't be
>          available in the backtrace.

Comment: FWIW, this functionality also exists on Mac OS X:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/backtrace.3.html

Comment: Windows has [CaptureStackBackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204633(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: On Linux with `glibc`, unfortunately, `backtrace_symbols` functions don't provide function name, source file name and line number.

Comment: In addition to using `-rdynamic`, also check that your build system doesn't add `-fvisibility=hidden` option! (as it will completely  discard the effect of `-rdynamic`)

Comment: Apple changed the link again! https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/backtrace.3.html (I know the URL says 'iPhoneOS' but the man page itself says 'This document is a Mac OS X manual page').

Comment: Tried this on mac and wired it to a `SIGABRT` handler. I compiled with `clang++` with `-g` and `-O0` which generated `a.out.dSYM`. To map from addresses to filenames and line numbers, you need to use [atos](https://www.manpagez.com/man/1/atos/) along with the crash reports obtained from `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports`. You'll need the first address under Binary Images to pass into the load address `-l` argument.

Answer (score 151):

**Survey of C/C++ backtrace methods**

In this answer I will try to run a single benchmark for a bunch of solutions to see which one runs faster, while also considering other points such as features and portability.

| Tool | Time / call | Line number | Function name | C++ demangling | Recompile | Signal safe | As string | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C++23 `<stacktrace>` GCC 12.1 | 7 us | y | y | y | y | n | y | n |
| Boost 1.74 `stacktrace()` | 5 us | y | y | y | y | n | y | n |
| Boost 1.74 `stacktrace::safe_dump_to` |  |  |  |  |  | y (deprecated) | n | n |
| glibc `backtrace_symbols_fd` | 25 us | n | `-rdynamic` | hacks | y | n | n | y |
| glibc `backtrace_symbols` | 21 us | n | `-rdynamic` | hacks | y | n | y | y |
| GDB scripting | 600 us | y | y | y | n | y | n | y |
| GDB code injection |  |  |  |  | n |  | n | y |
| libunwind |  |  |  |  | y |  |  |  |
| libdwfl | 4 ms | n |  |  | y |  |  |  |
| libbacktrace |  |  |  |  | y |  |  |  |
| cpptrace |  | y | y | y | n | y | y | y |

Empty cells mean "TODO", not "no".

- `us`: microsecond
- Line number: shows actual line number, not just function name + a memory address.

  It is usually possible to recover the line number from an address manually after the fact with `addr2line`. But it is a pain.
- Recompile: requires recompiling the program to get your traces. Not recompiling is better!
- Signal safe: crucial for the important uses case of "getting a stack trace in case of segfault": [How to automatically generate a stacktrace when my program crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77005/how-to-automatically-generate-a-stacktrace-when-my-program-crashes/74549444#74549444)
- As string: you get the stack trace as a string in the program itself, as opposed to e.g. just printing to stdout. Usually implies not signal safe, as we don't know the size of the stack trace string size in advance, and therefore requires malloc which is not async signal safe.
- C: does it work on a plain-C project (yes, there are still poor souls out there), or is C++ required?

**Test setup**

All benchmarks will run the following

main.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib> // strtoul

#include <mystacktrace.h>

void my_func_2(void) {
    print_stacktrace(); // line 6
}

void my_func_1(double f) {
    (void)f;
    my_func_2();
}

void my_func_1(int i) {
    (void)i;
    my_func_2(); // line 16
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    long long unsigned int n;
    if (argc > 1) {
        n = std::strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 0);
    } else {
        n = 1;
    }
    for (long long unsigned int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        my_func_1(1); // line 27
    }
}
```

This input is designed to test C++ name demangling since `my_func_1(int)` and `my_func_1(float)` [are necessarily mangled as a way to implement C++ function overload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c-in-c/30526795#30526795).

We differentiate between the benchmarks by using different `-I` includes to point to different implementations of `print_stacktrace()`.

Each benchmark is done with a command of form:

```
time ./stacktrace.out 100000 &>/dev/null
```

The number of iterations is adjusted for each implementation to produce a total runtime of the order of 1s for that benchmark.

`-O0` is used on all tests below unless noted. Stack traces may be irreparably mutilated by certain optimizations. Tail call optimization is a notable example of that: [What is tail call optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310974/what-is-tail-call-optimization/55230417#55230417) There's nothing we can do about it.

**C++23 `<stacktrace>`**

This method was previously mentioned at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69384663/895245 please consider upvoting that answer.

This is the best solution... it's portable, fast, shows line numbers and demangles C++ symbols. This option will displace every other alternative as soon as it becomes more widely available, with the exception perhaps only of GDB for one-offs without the need or recompilation.

cpp20_stacktrace/mystacktrace.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stacktrace>

void print_stacktrace() {
    std::cout << std::stacktrace::current();
}
```

GCC 12.1.0 from Ubuntu 22.04 does not have support compiled in, so for now I built it from source as per: [How to edit and re-build the GCC libstdc++ C++ standard library source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21872229/how-to-edit-and-re-build-the-gcc-libstdc-c-standard-library-source/51946224#51946224) and set `--enable-libstdcxx-backtrace=yes`, and it worked!

Compile with:

```
g++ -O0 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++23 -o cpp20_stacktrace.out main.cpp -lstdc++_libbacktrace
```

Sample output:

```
   0# print_stacktrace() at cpp20_stacktrace/mystacktrace.h:5
   1# my_func_2() at /home/ciro/main.cpp:6
   2# my_func_1(int) at /home/ciro/main.cpp:16
   3#      at /home/ciro/main.cpp:27
   4#      at :0
   5#      at :0
   6#      at :0
   7#
```

If we try to use GCC 12.1.0 from Ubuntu 22.04:

```
sudo apt install g++-12
g++-12 -ggdb3 -O2 -std=c++23 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o stacktrace.out stacktrace.cpp -lstdc++_libbacktrace
```

It fails with:

```
stacktrace.cpp: In function ‘void my_func_2()’:
stacktrace.cpp:6:23: error: ‘std::stacktrace’ has not been declared
    6 |     std::cout << std::stacktrace::current();
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~
```

Checking build options with:

```
g++-12 -v
```

does not show:

```
--enable-libstdcxx-backtrace=yes
```

so it wasn't compiled in. Bibliography:

- [How to use <stacktrace> in GCC trunk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70765285/how-to-use-stacktrace-in-gcc-trunk)
- [How can I generate a C++23 stacktrace with GCC 12.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72341483/how-can-i-generate-a-c23-stacktrace-with-gcc-12-1)

It does not fail on the include because the header file:

```
/usr/include/c++/12
```

has a feature check:

```
#if __cplusplus > 202002L && _GLIBCXX_HAVE_STACKTRACE
```

**Boost `stacktrace`**

The library has changed quite a lot around Ubuntu 22.04, so make sure your version matches: [Boost stack-trace not showing function names and line numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52583544/boost-stack-trace-not-showing-function-names-and-line-numbers)

The library is pretty much superseded by the more portable C++23 implementation, but remains a very good option for those that are not at that standard version yet, but already have a "Boost clearance".

Documented at: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/stacktrace/getting_started.html#stacktrace.getting_started.how_to_print_current_call_stack

Tested on Ubuntu 22.04, boost 1.74.0, you should do:

boost_stacktrace/mystacktrace.h

```
#include <iostream>

#define BOOST_STACKTRACE_LINK
#include <boost/stacktrace.hpp>

void print_stacktrace(void) {
    std::cout << boost::stacktrace::stacktrace();
}
```

On Ubuntu 19.10 boost 1.67.0 to get the line numbers we had to instead:

```
#include <iostream>

#define BOOST_STACKTRACE_USE_ADDR2LINE
#include <boost/stacktrace.hpp>

void print_stacktrace(void) {
    std::cout << boost::stacktrace::stacktrace();
}
```

which would call out to the `addr2line` executable and be 1000x slower than the newer Boost version.

The package `libboost-stacktrace-dev` did not exist at all on Ubuntu 16.04.

The rest of this section considers only the Ubuntu 22.04, boost 1.74 behaviour.

Compile:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-stacktrace-dev
g++ -O0 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++11 -o boost_stacktrace.out main.cpp -lboost_stacktrace_backtrace
```

Sample output:

```
 0# print_stacktrace() at boost_stacktrace/mystacktrace.h:7
 1# my_func_2() at /home/ciro/main.cpp:7
 2# my_func_1(int) at /home/ciro/main.cpp:17
 3# main at /home/ciro/main.cpp:26
 4# __libc_start_call_main at ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58
 5# __libc_start_main at ../csu/libc-start.c:379
 6# _start in ./boost_stacktrace.out
```

Note that the lines are off by one line. It was [suggested in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899870/print-call-stack-in-c-or-c/54365144#comment107446806_54365144) that this is because the following instruction address is being considered.

**Boost `stacktrace` header only**

What the `BOOST_STACKTRACE_LINK` does is to require `-lboost_stacktrace_backtrace` at link time, so we imagine without that it will just work. This would be a good option for devs who don't have the "Boost clearance" to just add as one offs to debug.

TODO unfortunately it didn't so well for me:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/stacktrace.hpp>

void print_stacktrace(void) {
    std::cout << boost::stacktrace::stacktrace();
}
```

then:

```
g++ -O0 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++11 -o boost_stacktrace_header_only.out main.cpp
```

contains the overly short output:

```
 0# 0x000055FF74AFB601 in ./boost_stacktrace_header_only.out
 1# 0x000055FF74AFB66C in ./boost_stacktrace_header_only.out
 2# 0x000055FF74AFB69C in ./boost_stacktrace_header_only.out
 3# 0x000055FF74AFB6F7 in ./boost_stacktrace_header_only.out
 4# 0x00007F0176E7BD90 in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
 5# __libc_start_main in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
 6# 0x000055FF74AFB4E5 in ./boost_stacktrace_header_only.out
```

which we can't even use with `addr2line`. Maybe we have to pass some other define from: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/stacktrace/configuration_and_build.html ?

Tested on Ubuntu 22.04. boost 1.74.

**Boost `boost::stacktrace::safe_dump_to`**

This is an interesting alternative to `boost::stacktrace::stacktrace` as it writes the stack trace in a async signal safe manner to a file, which makes it a good option for automatically dumping stack traces on segfaults which is a super common use case: [How to automatically generate a stacktrace when my program crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77005/how-to-automatically-generate-a-stacktrace-when-my-program-crashes/74549444#74549444)

Documented at: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost/stacktrace/safe_dump_1_3_38_7_6_2_1_6.html

TODO get it to work. All I see each time is a bunch of random bytes. My attempt:

boost_stacktrace_safe/mystacktrace.h

```
#include <unistd.h>

#define BOOST_STACKTRACE_LINK
#include <boost/stacktrace.hpp>

void print_stacktrace(void) {
    boost::stacktrace::safe_dump_to(0, 1024, STDOUT_FILENO);
}
```

Sample output:

```
1[FU1[FU"2[FU}2[FUm1@n10[FU
```

Changes drastically each time, suggesting it is random memory addresses.

Tested on Ubuntu 22.04, boost 1.74.0.

**glibc `backtrace`**

This method is quite portable as it comes with glibc itself. Documented at: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html

Tested on Ubuntu 22.04, glibc 2.35.

glibc_backtrace_symbols_fd/mystacktrace.h

```
#include <execinfo.h> /* backtrace, backtrace_symbols_fd */
#include <unistd.h> /* STDOUT_FILENO */

void print_stacktrace(void) {
    size_t size;
    enum Constexpr { MAX_SIZE = 1024 };
    void *array[MAX_SIZE];
    size = backtrace(array, MAX_SIZE);
    backtrace_symbols_fd(array, size, STDOUT_FILENO);
}
```

Compile with:

```
g++ -O0 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -rdynamic -std=c++11 -o glibc_backtrace_symbols_fd.out main.cpp
```

Sample output with `-rdynamic`:

```
./glibc_backtrace_symbols.out(_Z16print_stacktracev+0x47) [0x556e6a131230]
./glibc_backtrace_symbols.out(_Z9my_func_2v+0xd) [0x556e6a1312d6]
./glibc_backtrace_symbols.out(_Z9my_func_1i+0x14) [0x556e6a131306]
./glibc_backtrace_symbols.out(main+0x58) [0x556e6a131361]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x29d90) [0x7f175e7bdd90]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0x80) [0x7f175e7bde40]
./glibc_backtrace_symbols.out(_start+0x25) [0x556e6a131125]
```

Sample output without `-rdynamic`:

```
./glibc_backtrace_symbols_fd_no_rdynamic.out(+0x11f0)[0x556bd40461f0]
./glibc_backtrace_symbols_fd_no_rdynamic.out(+0x123c)[0x556bd404623c]
./glibc_backtrace_symbols_fd_no_rdynamic.out(+0x126c)[0x556bd404626c]
./glibc_backtrace_symbols_fd_no_rdynamic.out(+0x12c7)[0x556bd40462c7]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x29d90)[0x7f0da2b70d90]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0x80)[0x7f0da2b70e40]
./glibc_backtrace_symbols_fd_no_rdynamic.out(+0x10e5)[0x556bd40460e5]
```

To get the line numbers without `-rdynamic` we can use `addr2line`:

```
addr2line -C -e glibc_backtrace_symbols_fd_no_rdynamic.out 0x11f0 0x123c 0x126c 0x12c7
```

`addr2line` cannot unfortunately handle the function name + offset in function format of when we are not using `-rdynamic`, e.g. `_Z9my_func_2v+0xd`.

GDB can however:

```
gdb -nh -batch -ex 'info line *(_Z9my_func_2v+0xd)' -ex 'info line *(_Z9my_func_1i+0x14)' glibc_backtrace_symbols.out
Line 7 of "main.cpp" starts at address 0x12d6 <_Z9my_func_2v+13> and ends at 0x12d9 <_Z9my_func_1d>.
Line 17 of "main.cpp" starts at address 0x1306 <_Z9my_func_1i+20> and ends at 0x1309 <main(int, char**)>.
```

A helper to make it more bearable:

```
addr2lines() (
  perl -ne '$m = s/(.*).*\(([^)]*)\).*/gdb -nh -q -batch -ex "info line *\2" \1/;print $_ if $m' | bash
)
```

Usage:

```
xsel -b | addr2lines
```

**glibc `backtrace_symbols`**

A version of `backtrace_symbols_fd` that returns a string rather than printing to a file handle.

glibc_backtrace_symbols/mystacktrace.h

```
#include <execinfo.h> /* backtrace, backtrace_symbols */
#include <stdio.h> /* printf */

void print_stacktrace(void) {
    char **strings;
    size_t i, size;
    enum Constexpr { MAX_SIZE = 1024 };
    void *array[MAX_SIZE];
    size = backtrace(array, MAX_SIZE);
    strings = backtrace_symbols(array, size);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
    free(strings);
}
```

**glibc `backtrace` with C++ demangling hack 1: `-export-dynamic` + `dladdr`**

I couldn't find a simple way to automatically demangle C++ symbols with glibc `backtrace`.

- https://panthema.net/2008/0901-stacktrace-demangled/
- https://gist.github.com/fmela/591333/c64f4eb86037bb237862a8283df70cdfc25f01d3

Adapted from: https://gist.github.com/fmela/591333/c64f4eb86037bb237862a8283df70cdfc25f01d3

This is a "hack" because it requires changing the ELF with `-export-dynamic`.

glibc_ldl.cpp

```
#include <dlfcn.h>     // for dladdr
#include <cxxabi.h>    // for __cxa_demangle

#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

// This function produces a stack backtrace with demangled function & method names.
std::string backtrace(int skip = 1)
{
    void *callstack[128];
    const int nMaxFrames = sizeof(callstack) / sizeof(callstack[0]);
    char buf[1024];
    int nFrames = backtrace(callstack, nMaxFrames);
    char **symbols = backtrace_symbols(callstack, nFrames);

    std::ostringstream trace_buf;
    for (int i = skip; i < nFrames; i++) {
        Dl_info info;
        if (dladdr(callstack[i], &info)) {
            char *demangled = NULL;
            int status;
            demangled = abi::__cxa_demangle(info.dli_sname, NULL, 0, &status);
            std::snprintf(
                buf,
                sizeof(buf),
                "%-3d %*p %s + %zd\n",
                i,
                (int)(2 + sizeof(void*) * 2),
                callstack[i],
                status == 0 ? demangled : info.dli_sname,
                (char *)callstack[i] - (char *)info.dli_saddr
            );
            free(demangled);
        } else {
            std::snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%-3d %*p\n",
                i, (int)(2 + sizeof(void*) * 2), callstack[i]);
        }
        trace_buf << buf;
        std::snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%s\n", symbols[i]);
        trace_buf << buf;
    }
    free(symbols);
    if (nFrames == nMaxFrames)
        trace_buf << "[truncated]\n";
    return trace_buf.str();
}

void my_func_2(void) {
    std::cout << backtrace() << std::endl;
}

void my_func_1(double f) {
    (void)f;
    my_func_2();
}

void my_func_1(int i) {
    (void)i;
    my_func_2();
}

int main() {
    my_func_1(1);
    my_func_1(2.0);
}
```

Compile and run:

```
g++ -fno-pie -ggdb3 -O0 -no-pie -o glibc_ldl.out -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra \
  -pedantic-errors -fpic glibc_ldl.cpp -export-dynamic -ldl
./glibc_ldl.out
```

output:

```
1             0x40130a my_func_2() + 41
./glibc_ldl.out(_Z9my_func_2v+0x29) [0x40130a]
2             0x40139e my_func_1(int) + 16
./glibc_ldl.out(_Z9my_func_1i+0x10) [0x40139e]
3             0x4013b3 main + 18
./glibc_ldl.out(main+0x12) [0x4013b3]
4       0x7f7594552b97 __libc_start_main + 231
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7) [0x7f7594552b97]
5             0x400f3a _start + 42
./glibc_ldl.out(_start+0x2a) [0x400f3a]

1             0x40130a my_func_2() + 41
./glibc_ldl.out(_Z9my_func_2v+0x29) [0x40130a]
2             0x40138b my_func_1(double) + 18
./glibc_ldl.out(_Z9my_func_1d+0x12) [0x40138b]
3             0x4013c8 main + 39
./glibc_ldl.out(main+0x27) [0x4013c8]
4       0x7f7594552b97 __libc_start_main + 231
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7) [0x7f7594552b97]
5             0x400f3a _start + 42
./glibc_ldl.out(_start+0x2a) [0x400f3a]
```

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04.

**glibc `backtrace` with C++ demangling hack 2: parse backtrace output**

Shown at: https://panthema.net/2008/0901-stacktrace-demangled/

This is a hack because it requires parsing.

TODO get it to compile and show it here.

**GDB scripting**

We can also do this with GDB without recompiling by using: [How to do an specific action when a certain breakpoint is hit in GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517423/how-to-do-an-specific-action-when-a-certain-breakpoint-is-hit-in-gdb)

We setup an empty backtrace function for our testing:

gdb/mystacktrace.h

```
void print_stacktrace(void) {}
```

and then with:

main.gdb

```
start
break print_stacktrace
commands
  silent
  backtrace
  printf "\n"
  continue
end
continue
```

we can run:

```
gdb -nh -batch -x main.gdb --args gdb.out
```

Sample output:

```
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x11a7: file main.cpp, line 21.
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Temporary breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffc3e8) at main.cpp:21
warning: Source file is more recent than executable.
21          if (argc > 1) {
Breakpoint 2 at 0x555555555151: file gdb/mystacktrace.h, line 1.
#0  print_stacktrace () at gdb/mystacktrace.h:1
#1  0x0000555555555161 in my_func_2 () at main.cpp:6
#2  0x0000555555555191 in my_func_1 (i=1) at main.cpp:16
#3  0x00005555555551ec in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffc3e8) at main.cpp:27

[Inferior 1 (process 165453) exited normally]
```

The above can be made more usable with the following Bash function:

```
gdbbt() (
  tmpfile=$(mktemp /tmp/gdbbt.XXXXXX)
  fn="$1"
  shift
  printf '%s' "
start
break $fn
commands
  silent
  backtrace
  printf \"\n\"
  continue
end
continue
" > "$tmpfile"
  gdb -nh -batch -x "$tmpfile" -args "$@"
  rm -f "$tmpfile"
)
```

Usage:

```
gdbbt print_stacktrace gdb.out 2
```

I don't know how to make `commands` with `-ex` without the temporary file: [Problems adding a breakpoint with commands from command line with ex command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70941058/problems-adding-a-breakpoint-with-commands-from-command-line-with-ex-command)

Tested in Ubuntu 22.04, GDB 12.0.90.

**GDB code injection**

TODO this is the dream! It might allow for both compiled-liked speeds, but without the need to recompile! Either:

- with `compile code` + one of the other options, ideally C++23 `<stacktrace>`: [How to call assembly in gdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480868/how-to-call-assembly-in-gdb/31709579#31709579) Might already be possible. But `compile code` is mega-quirky so I'm lazy to even try
- a built-in `dbt` command analogous to `dprintf` dynamic printf: [How to do an specific action when a certain breakpoint is hit in GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517423/how-to-do-an-specific-action-when-a-certain-breakpoint-is-hit-in-gdb/42673618#42673618)

**libunwind**

TODO does this have any advantage over glibc backtrace? Very similar output, also requires modifying the build command, but not part of glibc so requires an extra package installation.

Code adapted from: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/programmatic-access-to-the-call-stack-in-c/

main.c

```
/* This must be on top. */
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Paste this on the file you want to debug. */
#define UNW_LOCAL_ONLY
#include <libunwind.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void print_trace() {
    char sym[256];
    unw_context_t context;
    unw_cursor_t cursor;
    unw_getcontext(&context);
    unw_init_local(&cursor, &context);
    while (unw_step(&cursor) > 0) {
        unw_word_t offset, pc;
        unw_get_reg(&cursor, UNW_REG_IP, &pc);
        if (pc == 0) {
            break;
        }
        printf("0x%lx:", pc);
        if (unw_get_proc_name(&cursor, sym, sizeof(sym), &offset) == 0) {
            printf(" (%s+0x%lx)\n", sym, offset);
        } else {
            printf(" -- error: unable to obtain symbol name for this frame\n");
        }
    }
    puts("");
}

void my_func_3(void) {
    print_trace();
}

void my_func_2(void) {
    my_func_3();
}

void my_func_1(void) {
    my_func_3();
}

int main(void) {
    my_func_1(); /* line 46 */
    my_func_2(); /* line 47 */
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and run:

```
sudo apt-get install libunwind-dev
gcc -fno-pie -ggdb3 -O3 -no-pie -o main.out -std=c99 \
  -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors main.c -lunwind
```

Either `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` must be on top, or we must use `-std=gnu99`:

- [Is the type `stack_t` no longer defined on linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778735/is-the-type-stack-t-no-longer-defined-on-linux)
- [Glibc - error in ucontext.h, but only with -std=c11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32426835/glibc-error-in-ucontext-h-but-only-with-std-c11)

Run:

```
./main.out
```

Output:

```
0x4007db: (main+0xb)
0x7f4ff50aa830: (__libc_start_main+0xf0)
0x400819: (_start+0x29)

0x4007e2: (main+0x12)
0x7f4ff50aa830: (__libc_start_main+0xf0)
0x400819: (_start+0x29)
```

and:

```
addr2line -e main.out 0x4007db 0x4007e2
```

gives:

```
/home/ciro/main.c:34
/home/ciro/main.c:49
```

With `-O0`:

```
0x4009cf: (my_func_3+0xe)
0x4009e7: (my_func_1+0x9)
0x4009f3: (main+0x9)
0x7f7b84ad7830: (__libc_start_main+0xf0)
0x4007d9: (_start+0x29)

0x4009cf: (my_func_3+0xe)
0x4009db: (my_func_2+0x9)
0x4009f8: (main+0xe)
0x7f7b84ad7830: (__libc_start_main+0xf0)
0x4007d9: (_start+0x29)
```

and:

```
addr2line -e main.out 0x4009f3 0x4009f8
```

gives:

```
/home/ciro/main.c:47
/home/ciro/main.c:48
```

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04, GCC 6.4.0, libunwind 1.1.

**libunwind with C++ name demangling**

Code adapted from: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/programmatic-access-to-the-call-stack-in-c/

unwind.cpp

```
#define UNW_LOCAL_ONLY
#include <cxxabi.h>
#include <libunwind.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

void backtrace() {
  unw_cursor_t cursor;
  unw_context_t context;

  // Initialize cursor to current frame for local unwinding.
  unw_getcontext(&context);
  unw_init_local(&cursor, &context);

  // Unwind frames one by one, going up the frame stack.
  while (unw_step(&cursor) > 0) {
    unw_word_t offset, pc;
    unw_get_reg(&cursor, UNW_REG_IP, &pc);
    if (pc == 0) {
      break;
    }
    std::printf("0x%lx:", pc);

    char sym[256];
    if (unw_get_proc_name(&cursor, sym, sizeof(sym), &offset) == 0) {
      char* nameptr = sym;
      int status;
      char* demangled = abi::__cxa_demangle(sym, nullptr, nullptr, &status);
      if (status == 0) {
        nameptr = demangled;
      }
      std::printf(" (%s+0x%lx)\n", nameptr, offset);
      std::free(demangled);
    } else {
      std::printf(" -- error: unable to obtain symbol name for this frame\n");
    }
  }
}

void my_func_2(void) {
    backtrace();
    std::cout << std::endl; // line 43
}

void my_func_1(double f) {
    (void)f;
    my_func_2();
}

void my_func_1(int i) {
    (void)i;
    my_func_2();
}  // line 54

int main() {
    my_func_1(1);
    my_func_1(2.0);
}
```

Compile and run:

```
sudo apt-get install libunwind-dev
g++ -fno-pie -ggdb3 -O0 -no-pie -o unwind.out -std=c++11 \
  -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors unwind.cpp -lunwind -pthread
./unwind.out
```

Output:

```
0x400c80: (my_func_2()+0x9)
0x400cb7: (my_func_1(int)+0x10)
0x400ccc: (main+0x12)
0x7f4c68926b97: (__libc_start_main+0xe7)
0x400a3a: (_start+0x2a)

0x400c80: (my_func_2()+0x9)
0x400ca4: (my_func_1(double)+0x12)
0x400ce1: (main+0x27)
0x7f4c68926b97: (__libc_start_main+0xe7)
0x400a3a: (_start+0x2a)
```

and then we can find the lines of `my_func_2` and `my_func_1(int)` with:

```
addr2line -e unwind.out 0x400c80 0x400cb7
```

which gives:

```
/home/ciro/test/unwind.cpp:43
/home/ciro/test/unwind.cpp:54
```

TODO: why are the lines off by one?

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04, GCC 7.4.0, libunwind 1.2.1.

**Linux kernel**

[How to print the current thread stack trace inside the Linux kernel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143924/how-to-print-the-current-thread-stack-trace-inside-the-linux-kernel)

**libdwfl**

This was originally mentioned at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60713161/895245 and it might be the best method, but I have to benchmark a bit more, but please go upvote that answer.

TODO: I tried to minimize the code in that answer, which was working, to a single function, but it is segfaulting, let me know if anyone can find why.

dwfl.cpp: answer reached 30k chars and this was the easiest cut: https://gist.github.com/cirosantilli/f1dd3ee5d324b9d24e40f855723544ac

Compile and run:

```
sudo apt install libdw-dev libunwind-dev
g++ -fno-pie -ggdb3 -O0 -no-pie -o dwfl.out -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors dwfl.cpp -ldw -lunwind
./dwfl.out
```

We also need libunwind as that makes results more correct. If you do without it, it runs, but you will see that some of the lines are a bit wrong.

Output:

```
0: 0x402b72 stacktrace[abi:cxx11]() at /home/ciro/test/dwfl.cpp:65
1: 0x402cda my_func_2() at /home/ciro/test/dwfl.cpp:100
2: 0x402d76 my_func_1(int) at /home/ciro/test/dwfl.cpp:111
3: 0x402dd1 main at /home/ciro/test/dwfl.cpp:122
4: 0x7ff227ea0d8f __libc_start_call_main at ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58
5: 0x7ff227ea0e3f __libc_start_main@@GLIBC_2.34 at ../csu/libc-start.c:392
6: 0x402534 _start at ../csu/libc-start.c:-1

0: 0x402b72 stacktrace[abi:cxx11]() at /home/ciro/test/dwfl.cpp:65
1: 0x402cda my_func_2() at /home/ciro/test/dwfl.cpp:100
2: 0x402d5f my_func_1(double) at /home/ciro/test/dwfl.cpp:106
3: 0x402de2 main at /home/ciro/test/dwfl.cpp:123
4: 0x7ff227ea0d8f __libc_start_call_main at ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58
5: 0x7ff227ea0e3f __libc_start_main@@GLIBC_2.34 at ../csu/libc-start.c:392
6: 0x402534 _start at ../csu/libc-start.c:-1
```

Benchmark run:

```
g++ -fno-pie -ggdb3 -O3 -no-pie -o dwfl.out -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors dwfl.cpp -ldw
time ./dwfl.out 1000 >/dev/null
```

Output:

```
real    0m3.751s
user    0m2.822s
sys     0m0.928s
```

So we see that this method is 10x faster than Boost's stacktrace, and might therefore be applicable to more use cases.

Tested in Ubuntu 22.04 amd64, libdw-dev 0.186, libunwind 1.3.2.

**libbacktrace**

https://github.com/ianlancetaylor/libbacktrace

Considering the harcore library author, it is worth trying this out, maybe it is The One. TODO check it out.

> A C library that may be linked into a C/C++ program to produce symbolic backtraces
>
> As of October 2020, libbacktrace supports ELF, PE/COFF, Mach-O, and XCOFF executables with DWARF debugging information. In other words, it supports GNU/Linux, *BSD, macOS, Windows, and AIX. The library is written to make it straightforward to add support for other object file and debugging formats.
>
> The library relies on the C++ unwind API defined at https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi-eh.html This API is provided by GCC and clang.

**See also**

- [How can one grab a stack trace in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105659/how-can-one-grab-a-stack-trace-in-c)
- [How to make backtrace()/backtrace_symbols() print the function names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934659/how-to-make-backtrace-backtrace-symbols-print-the-function-names)
- [Is there a portable/standard-compliant way to get filenames and linenumbers in a stack trace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40751832/is-there-a-portable-standard-compliant-way-to-get-filenames-and-linenumbers-in-a)
- [Best way to invoke gdb from inside program to print its stacktrace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151779/best-way-to-invoke-gdb-from-inside-program-to-print-its-stacktrace)
- automatic stack trace on failure:

  - on C++ exception: [How to display a stack trace when an exception is thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691719/c-display-stack-trace-on-exception)
  - generic: [How to automatically generate a stacktrace when my program crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77005/how-to-automatically-generate-a-stacktrace-when-my-program-crashes)

**[cpptrace](https://github.com/jeremy-rifkin/cpptrace)**

Cpptrace is simple and portable supporting C++11 and newer. Unlike other solutions it supports all major platforms and compilers and is almost entirely self-contained.

```cpp
cpptrace::generate_trace().print();
```

Sample output:

```
Stack trace (most recent call first):
#0 0x000055fb1305f235 in my_func_2() at /path/to/main.cpp:6
#1 0x000055fb1305f2b5 in my_func_1(int) at /path/to/main.cpp:16
#2 0x000055fb1305f310 in main at /path/to/main.cpp:27
#3 0x00007f648990cd8f in __libc_start_call_main at ./csu/../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58
#4 0x00007f648990ce3f in __libc_start_main_impl at ./csu/../csu/libc-start.c:392
#5 0x000055fb1305f144 in _start at ./stacktrace.out
```

In addition to general stacktrace generation it includes a traced exception object that generates a trace when thrown and allows for generation of raw stack traces that can be resolved later.

More information can be found [here](https://github.com/jeremy-rifkin/cpptrace).

Comment: All the "TODO: lines off by one" are because the line number is taken from the start of the next expression.

Comment: Using the `libdwfl` approach I get module names fine, but no source file/line number.  Intead, `dwfl_module_getsrc` always returns 21 "address out of range".  Do you have any suggestion as to what might be wrong or how I can troubleshoot this?  (This happens with or without a `debuginfo_path` that points to every directory any exe or `.o` file is in.)

Comment: I should also say w.r.t. the issue of not getting file/line#s: I am using `clang` with `--unwindlib=libgcc`, rather than `-lunwind` which didn't seem to work.

Comment: @davidbak I've just retested the libdwfl example and it worked on Ubuntu 22.04. Why are you trying to pass `-lunwind` to a dwfl example?

Comment: Because in [the answer by Egorushkin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60713161/751579) which you reference he passes in both `-lunwind` and `-ldw`?  And in addition says: "When no `-lunwind` is linked, it produces a less accurate stacktrace". I'll try it without `--unwindlib=libgcc` then (just using `-ldw` which is obviously needed).  My guess in fact is that some other setting in the project - which is complex and I don't fully understand the build system (Bitcoin Core) is doing something unexpected (and bad) to the debug information.  Not sure what though.  (Oh, I'm using `-ggdb3` flag too.)

Comment: (thank you for taking the time to look at this)

Comment: @davidbak ah, OK, I hadn't seen that. I hadn't noticed, but some of the lines were actually slightly wrong without `-libunwind`. Updated to use it. clang is definitely the biggest suspicion in your case then.

Answer (score 13):

In C++23, there will be `<stacktrace>`, and then you can do:

```
#include <stacktrace>

/* ... */

std::cout << std::stacktrace::current();
```

Further details:
  • https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/stacktrace 
  • https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/basic_stacktrace/operator_ltlt

Answer (score 11):

Another answer to an old thread.

When I need to do this, I usually just use `system()` and `pstack`

So something like this:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>

void f()
{
    pid_t myPid = getpid();
    std::string pstackCommand = "pstack ";
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << myPid;
    pstackCommand += ss.str();
    system(pstackCommand.c_str());
}

void g()
{
   f();
}


void h()
{
   g();
}

int main()
{
   h();
}
```

This outputs

```
#0  0x00002aaaab62d61e in waitpid () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00002aaaab5bf609 in do_system () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x0000000000400c3c in f() ()
#3  0x0000000000400cc5 in g() ()
#4  0x0000000000400cd1 in h() ()
#5  0x0000000000400cdd in main ()
```

This should work on Linux, FreeBSD and Solaris (on FreeBSD the "bstack" port works better than "pstack"). I don't think that macOS has pstack or a simple equivalent, but this [thread seems to have an alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523118/pstack-a-process-on-osx-10-9).

If you are using `C`, then you will need to use `C` string functions.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void f()
{
    pid_t myPid = getpid();
    /*
      length of command 7 for 'pstack ', 7 for the PID, 1 for nul
    */
    char pstackCommand[7+7+1];
    sprintf(pstackCommand, "pstack %d", (int)myPid);
    system(pstackCommand);
}
```

I've used 7 for the max number of digits in the PID, based on [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/279178/what-is-the-range-of-a-pid-on-linux-and-solaris).

Comment: Good point, since the subject does ask for C. No it would need adapting, since std::string is C++ only. I will update my answer with  a C version.

Answer (score 9):

Linux specific, TLDR:

1. [`backtrace`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/backtrace.3.html) in `glibc` produces accurate stacktraces only when `-lunwind` is linked (undocumented platform-specific feature).
2. To output *function name*, *source file* and *line number* use [`#include <elfutils/libdwfl.h>`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=elfutils.git;a=blob;f=libdwfl/libdwfl.h;h=d5fa06d476bd90cd3c3f83c1805014f4b5cdb49d;hb=HEAD) (this library is documented only in its header file). `backtrace_symbols` and `backtrace_symbolsd_fd` are least informative.

---

On modern Linux your can get the stacktrace addresses using function [`backtrace`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/backtrace.3.html). The undocumented way to make `backtrace` produce more accurate addresses on popular platforms is to link with [`-lunwind`](https://www.nongnu.org/libunwind/docs.html) (`libunwind-dev` on Ubuntu 18.04) (see the example output below). `backtrace` uses function `_Unwind_Backtrace` and by default the latter comes from `libgcc_s.so.1` and that implementation is most portable. When `-lunwind` is linked it provides a more accurate version of `_Unwind_Backtrace` but this library is less portable (see supported architectures in [`libunwind/src`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=libunwind.git;a=tree;f=src;hb=HEAD)).

Unfortunately, the companion `backtrace_symbolsd` and `backtrace_symbols_fd` functions have not been able to resolve the stacktrace addresses to function names with source file name and line number for probably a decade now (see the example output below).

However, there is another method to resolve addresses to symbols and it produces the most useful traces with *function name*, *source file* and *line number*. The method is to `#include <elfutils/libdwfl.h>`and link with `-ldw` (`libdw-dev` on Ubuntu 18.04).

Working C++ example (`test.cc`):

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

#include <boost/core/demangle.hpp>

#include <execinfo.h>
#include <elfutils/libdwfl.h>

struct DebugInfoSession {
    Dwfl_Callbacks callbacks = {};
    char* debuginfo_path = nullptr;
    Dwfl* dwfl = nullptr;

    DebugInfoSession() {
        callbacks.find_elf = dwfl_linux_proc_find_elf;
        callbacks.find_debuginfo = dwfl_standard_find_debuginfo;
        callbacks.debuginfo_path = &debuginfo_path;

        dwfl = dwfl_begin(&callbacks);
        assert(dwfl);

        int r;
        r = dwfl_linux_proc_report(dwfl, getpid());
        assert(!r);
        r = dwfl_report_end(dwfl, nullptr, nullptr);
        assert(!r);
        static_cast<void>(r);
    }

    ~DebugInfoSession() {
        dwfl_end(dwfl);
    }

    DebugInfoSession(DebugInfoSession const&) = delete;
    DebugInfoSession& operator=(DebugInfoSession const&) = delete;
};

struct DebugInfo {
    void* ip;
    std::string function;
    char const* file;
    int line;

    DebugInfo(DebugInfoSession const& dis, void* ip)
        : ip(ip)
        , file()
        , line(-1)
    {
        // Get function name.
        uintptr_t ip2 = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(ip);
        Dwfl_Module* module = dwfl_addrmodule(dis.dwfl, ip2);
        char const* name = dwfl_module_addrname(module, ip2);
        function = name ? boost::core::demangle(name) : "<unknown>";

        // Get source filename and line number.
        if(Dwfl_Line* dwfl_line = dwfl_module_getsrc(module, ip2)) {
            Dwarf_Addr addr;
            file = dwfl_lineinfo(dwfl_line, &addr, &line, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
        }
    }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, DebugInfo const& di) {
    s << di.ip << ' ' << di.function;
    if(di.file)
        s << " at " << di.file << ':' << di.line;
    return s;
}

void terminate_with_stacktrace() {
    void* stack[512];
    int stack_size = ::backtrace(stack, sizeof stack / sizeof *stack);

    // Print the exception info, if any.
    if(auto ex = std::current_exception()) {
        try {
            std::rethrow_exception(ex);
        }
        catch(std::exception& e) {
            std::cerr << "Fatal exception " << boost::core::demangle(typeid(e).name()) << ": " << e.what() << ".\n";
        }
        catch(...) {
            std::cerr << "Fatal unknown exception.\n";
        }
    }

    DebugInfoSession dis;
    std::cerr << "Stacktrace of " << stack_size << " frames:\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < stack_size; ++i) {
        std::cerr << i << ": " << DebugInfo(dis, stack[i]) << '\n';
    }
    std::cerr.flush();

    std::_Exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main() {
    std::set_terminate(terminate_with_stacktrace);
    throw std::runtime_error("test exception");
}
```

Compiled on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS with gcc-8.3:

```
g++ -o test.o -c -m{arch,tune}=native -std=gnu++17 -W{all,extra,error} -g -Og -fstack-protector-all test.cc
g++ -o test -g test.o -ldw -lunwind
```

Outputs:

```
Fatal exception std::runtime_error: test exception.
Stacktrace of 7 frames:
0: 0x55f3837c1a8c terminate_with_stacktrace() at /home/max/src/test/test.cc:76
1: 0x7fbc1c845ae5 <unknown>
2: 0x7fbc1c845b20 std::terminate()
3: 0x7fbc1c845d53 __cxa_throw
4: 0x55f3837c1a43 main at /home/max/src/test/test.cc:103
5: 0x7fbc1c3e3b96 __libc_start_main at ../csu/libc-start.c:310
6: 0x55f3837c17e9 _start
```

When no `-lunwind` is linked, it produces a less accurate stacktrace:

```
0: 0x5591dd9d1a4d terminate_with_stacktrace() at /home/max/src/test/test.cc:76
1: 0x7f3c18ad6ae6 <unknown>
2: 0x7f3c18ad6b21 <unknown>
3: 0x7f3c18ad6d54 <unknown>
4: 0x5591dd9d1a04 main at /home/max/src/test/test.cc:103
5: 0x7f3c1845cb97 __libc_start_main at ../csu/libc-start.c:344
6: 0x5591dd9d17aa _start
```

For comparison, `backtrace_symbols_fd` output for the same stacktrace is least informative:

```
/home/max/src/test/debug/gcc/test(+0x192f)[0x5601c5a2092f]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0x92ae5)[0x7f95184f5ae5]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZSt9terminatev+0x10)[0x7f95184f5b20]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(__cxa_throw+0x43)[0x7f95184f5d53]
/home/max/src/test/debug/gcc/test(+0x1ae7)[0x5601c5a20ae7]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe6)[0x7f9518093b96]
/home/max/src/test/debug/gcc/test(+0x1849)[0x5601c5a20849]
```

In a production version (as well as C language version) you may like to make this code extra robust by replacing `boost::core::demangle`, `std::string` and `std::cout` with their underlying calls.

You can also override `__cxa_throw` to capture the stacktrace when an exception is thrown and print it when the exception is caught. By the time it enters `catch` block the stack has been unwound, so it is too late to call `backtrace`, and this is why the stack must be captured on `throw` which is implemented by function [`__cxa_throw`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/610e1f88b0610ddf517673b010e07f7b74d7088c/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/libsupc%2B%2B/cxxabi.h#L614). Note that in a multi-threaded program `__cxa_throw` can be called simultaneously by multiple threads, so that if it captures the stacktrace into a global array that must be `thread_local`.

You can also make the stack trace printing function [async-signal safe](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html), so that you can invoke it directly from your `SIGSEGV`, `SIGBUS` signal handlers (which should use their own stacks for robustness). Obtaining *function name*, *source file* and *line number* using   `libdwfl` from a signal handler may fail because it is not async-signal safe or if the address space of the process has been substantially corrupted, but in practice it succeeds 99% of the time (I haven't seen it fail).

---

To summarize, a complete production-ready library for automatic stacktrace output should:

1. Capture the stacktrace on `throw` into thread-specific storage.
2. Automatically print the stacktrace on unhandled exceptions.
3. Print the stacktrace in async-signal-safe manner.
4. Provide a robust signal handler function which uses its own stack that prints the stacktrace in a async-signal-safe manner. The user can install this function as a signal handler for `SIGSEGV`, `SIGBUS`, `SIGFPE`, etc..
5. The signal handler may as well print the values of all CPU registers at the point of the fault from `ucontext_t` signal function argument (may be excluding vector registers), a-la Linux kernel oops log messages.

Comment: That `-lunwind` issue got discovered while making this post, I previously used `libunwind` directly to obtain the stacktrace and was going to post it, but `backtrace` does it for me when `-lunwind` is linked.

Comment: How is the `_Unwind_backtrace` from GCC less portable than that from libunwind?

Comment: @S.S.Anne I say that gcc version is _most_ portable because it is used for `catch`.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why? Is it hand-written in asm?

Comment: @S.S.Anne May be because the original author of the library [David Mosberger](https://dl.acm.org/profile/81100373376) was focused on IA-64 initially but then the library got more traction https://www.nongnu.org/libunwind/people.html . `gcc` doesn't expose the API, is that right?

Comment: Using this approach I get module names fine, but no source file/line number.  Intead, `dwfl_module_getsrc` always returns 21 "address out of range".  Do you have any suggestion as to what might be wrong or how I can troubleshoot this?  (This happens with or without a `debuginfo_path` that points to every directory any exe or `.o` file is in.)

Comment: I should also say w.r.t. the issue of not getting file/line#s: I am using `clang` with `--unwindlib=libgcc`, rather than `-lunwind` which didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 8):

> Is there any way to dump the call stack in a running process in C or C++ every time a certain function is called?

You can use a macro  function instead of return statement in the specific function.

For example, instead of using return,

```
int foo(...)
{
    if (error happened)
        return -1;

    ... do something ...

    return 0
}
```

You can use a macro function.

```
#include "c-callstack.h"

int foo(...)
{
    if (error happened)
        NL_RETURN(-1);

    ... do something ...

    NL_RETURN(0);
}
```

Whenever an error happens in a function, you will see Java-style call stack as shown below.

```
Error(code:-1) at : so_topless_ranking_server (sample.c:23)
Error(code:-1) at : nanolat_database (sample.c:31)
Error(code:-1) at : nanolat_message_queue (sample.c:39)
Error(code:-1) at : main (sample.c:47)
```

Full source code is available here.

[c-callstack at https://github.com/Nanolat](https://github.com/Nanolat/c-callstack)

Answer (score 6):

There is no standardized way to do that. For windows the functionality is provided in the [DbgHelp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679309(v=VS.85).aspx) library

Comment: Any examples? all I get from msdn is that it's only functionality is getting symbols, nothing about call stack

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Boost libraries to print the current callstack.

```
#include <boost/stacktrace.hpp>

// ... somewhere inside the `bar(int)` function that is called recursively:
std::cout << boost::stacktrace::stacktrace();
```

Man here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/stacktrace.html

Comment: I got an error `cannot locate SymEnumSymbolsExW at C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dbgeng.dll` on Win10.

Answer (score 3):

I know this thread is old, but I think it can be useful for other people. If you are using gcc, you can use its instrument features (-finstrument-functions option) to log any function call (entry and exit). Have a look at this for more information: http://hacktalks.blogspot.fr/2013/08/gcc-instrument-functions.html

You can thus for instance push and pop every calls into a stack, and when you want to print it, you just look at what you have in your stack.

I've tested it, it works perfectly and is very handy

UPDATE: you can also find information about the -finstrument-functions compile option in the GCC doc concerning the Instrumentation options: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html

Comment: You should also link to GCC docs in case the article goes down.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I've thus added an UPDATE in my post with a link to the gcc doc

Answer (score 2):

You can implement the functionality yourself:

Use a global (string)stack and at start of each function push the function name and such other values (eg parameters) onto this stack; at exit of function pop it again.

Write a function that will printout the stack content when it is called, and use this in the function where you want to see the callstack.

This may sound like a lot of work but is quite useful.

Comment: I would not do that. Rather, I'd create a wrapper which uses the underlying platform specific APIs (see below). The amount of work would be probably the same, but the investment should pay off faster.

Comment: @paul: your answer refers to windows when the OP clearly specifies linux ... but could be useful for windows-guys who show up here.

Comment: Right, I overlooked that..Hm, it's the last sentence of the question, so maybe the poster should modify his request to mention his/her target platform in a more prominent place.

Comment: This would be a good idea, except my codebase includes a few dozen files containing a few hundred (if not a few thousand) files, so this is unfeasible.

Comment: maybe not if you hack-up a sed/perl script to add after each function declaration `call_registror MY_SUPERSECRETNAME(__FUNCTION__);` which pushes the argument in its constructor and pops in its destructor __FUNCTION__ always represents the name of the current function.

Comment: @flownt: that's a neat & tidy way of doing it - one to remember.

Answer (score 2):

Of course the next question is: will this be enough ?

The main disadvantage of stack-traces is that why you have the precise function being called you do not have anything else, like the value of its arguments, which is very useful for debugging.

If you have access to gcc and gdb, I would suggest using `assert` to check for a specific condition, and produce a memory dump if it is not met. Of course this means the process will stop, but you'll have a full fledged report instead of a mere stack-trace.

If you wish for a less obtrusive way, you can always use logging. There are very efficient logging facilities out there, like [Pantheios](http://pantheios.sourceforge.net/) for example. Which once again could give you a much more accurate image of what is going on.

Comment: Of course it may not be enough, but if I can see that the function is called in place with one configuration and not with the other, then that's a pretty good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Poppy](https://github.com/orling/Poppy) for this. It is normally used to gather the stack trace during a crash but it can also output it for a running program as well.

Now here's the good part: it can output the actual parameter values for each function on the stack, and even local variables, loop counters, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GNU profiler. It shows the call-graph as well! the command is `gprof` and you need to compile your code with some option.

Answer (score 0):

With QT, this is a selective approach what to print in output.

ccallstack.h

```
`#define CALLSTACK CCallStack c(QDateTime::currentDateTime(),__FILE__,__LINE__,__FUNCTION__,"")
#define CALLSTACK2(comment) CCallStack c(QDateTime::currentDateTime(),__FILE__,__LINE__,__FUNCTION__,comment)
/**************************************************/
class CCallStack
{
    private:
        QString FunctionName;
        static QStringList Stack;
    public:
        CCallStack(QDateTime date,cstr file,int line,cstr functionName,cstr comment);
        CCallStack(cstr functionName);
        ~CCallStack();
        static void print();
};
```

`

ccallstack.cpp

```
 #include "ccallstack.h"
QStringList CCallStack::Stack;

CCallStack::CCallStack(QDateTime date,cstr file,int line,cstr functionName,cstr comment)
{
    QString s =
        QString("%1 file://%2:%3\033[35m %4\033[0m \033[34m:%5").arg(date.toString("HH:mm:ss:zzz")).arg(file).arg(
                line).arg(
                functionName).arg(comment);
    FunctionName = s;
    Stack.append(s);
}

CCallStack::CCallStack(cstr functionName):
    FunctionName(functionName)
{
    Stack.append(functionName);
}

CCallStack::~CCallStack()
{
    QString lastName = Stack.last();
    if (lastName!=FunctionName)
    {
        qWarning() << "There is a thread or Event Order conflict.";
        print();
    }
    Stack.removeLast();
}
void CCallStack::print()
{
    int index = 0;
    qDebug().nospace().noquote() << "STACKTRACE OUTPUT Stack Count:" << Stack.count();
    foreach(QString name,Stack)
    {
        qDebug().nospace().noquote() << index << ":" << name;
        index++;
    }
    qDebug().nospace().noquote() << "END OF STACKTRACE OUTPUT";
}
```

usage:
register a function using:

```
foo (){
   CALLSTACK
   ...
}
```

or

```
CALLSTACK2("this is a function to trace");
```

Then just call like:

```
CException::CException(cstr err):
{
    CCallStack::print();
}
```

outputs:

```
STACKTRACE OUTPUT Stack Count:6
0:09:18:26:505 file://..\main_app\entities\cdesktopsession.cpp:1034 CDesktopSession::sl_updateTimer_triggerred :
1:09:18:26:505 file://..\main_app\entities\cdesktopentity.cpp:161 CDesktopEntity::processTimeTick :Freeze_Frame_Index_Number
2:09:18:26:505 file://..\main_app\entities\cdesktopfield.cpp:154 CDesktopField::updateEntity :Freeze_Frame_Index_Number
3:09:18:26:505 file://..\main_app\entities\cdesktopa2lsinglevalue.cpp:299 CDesktopA2LSingleValue::getA2LValue :Freeze_Frame_Index_Number
4:09:18:26:505 file://..\main_app\device\ccandevicexcp.cpp:302 CCanDeviceXCP::requestAddressValue_internal :
5:09:18:26:505 file://..\main_app\device\ccandevice.cpp:72 CCanDevice::sendFrame_internal :
END OF STACKTRACE OUTPUT
```

Simple and usefull...

Answer (score -5):

> Is there any way to dump the call stack in a running process in C or C++ every time a certain function is called?

No there is not, although platform-dependent solutions might exist.