# Is the type `stack_t` no longer defined on linux?

Tags: c, linux, ucontext

The linux platform is Ubuntu 12.04

I have the following headers included in my source code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <ucontext.h>

...
```

When I compile it however, it complains `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/ucontext.h:139:5: error: unknown type name 'stack_t'`

I googled and found that `stack_t` should be defined in `signal.h`, but here it doesn't seem to be defined?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is meant to be a comment but I cannot make it readable there.  Sorry.

Did you `#define`  one of the following:

```
 _BSD_SOURCE || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 500 ||
           _XOPEN_SOURCE && _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED
           || /* Since glibc 2.12: */ _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200809L
```

Comment: Thanks!
defining `_BSD_SOURCE` fixed my problem. I guess my question now is why is this needed to enable `stack_t` on linux?

Comment: @BeyondSora: `stack_t` is non-standard. Anything that is non-standard are enabled by using [feature test macros](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html).

Comment: You may be using `-std=c99` or `-std=c11`; you may be better off using `-std=gnu99` or `-std=gnu11`.  Or you can add an appropriate POSIX define (`#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` for example), or (as you seem to have chosen) `#define _BSD_SOURCE`.  Deciding when to make the extra facilities available and when not to do so is complex.

Answer (score 4):

According to SUS v2 (1997), `stack_t` should be defined in `<signal.h>` - http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/ucontext.h.html

> The types sigset_t and stack_t are defined as in .

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/signal.h.html

> The  header defines the stack_t type as a structure that includes at least the following members:

```
void     *ss_sp       stack base or pointer
size_t    ss_size     stack size
int       ss_flags    flags
```

The type is also listed in glibc documentation: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Signal-Stack.html

> Data Type: stack_t

This type is used in `sigaltstack` function, described as:

> sigaltstack is the newer interface, and comes from 4.4 BSD. ...

And the official Linux man page for `sigaltstack` (version 2015-07-23) says: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaltstack.2.html

> Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see [feature_test_macros(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html)):

```
   sigaltstack():
       _BSD_SOURCE || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 500 ||
       _XOPEN_SOURCE && _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED
       || /* Since glibc 2.12: */ _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200809L
```

> CONFORMING TO    POSIX.1-2001, POSIX.1-2009, SUSv2, SVr4.

So, when you use glibc newer than 2.12, you must define some of macro to be able to use `sigaltstack` and `stack_t`. Since glibc 2.10 you can just define `#define _GNU_SOURCE` to enable `_BSD_SOURCE` and `_POSIX_C_SOURCE = 200809L`