# Implement setjmp and longjmp functionality with ucontext

Tags: c, posix, setjmp, ucontext

I am trying to grasp some key concepts in order to fully understand the **ucontext** and **setjmp** libraries.

On what concerns **ucontext**:

- **User context**, eg program counter and stack register.
- Is saved on a **ucontext_t** type when executing **getcontext**
- Activates a previously saved context via **setcontext** (this implies that the context was stored with **getcontext**)
- Swaps context with **swapcontext** by **saving the current program state and starts executing by the 2nd context since we will load the previously stored context**

Some sample code I tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ucontext.h>
int main() {
  // if you use the register storage identifier
  // the variable will be stored at the CPU
  // and since no change will be noticed it will be swaping forever
  /*register*/ int done = 0;
  ucontext_t one;
  ucontext_t two;

  getcontext(&one);

  printf("hello \n");

  if (!done) {
    printf("about to swap \n");
    done = 1;
    swapcontext(&two, &one);
  }
}
```

On what concerns **setjmp and longjmp**:

- Pretty much a **global goto**, the caveat is that since we will be jumping outside the current scope, we need to somehow store the **state aka context when we jump back**
- **setjmp sets the point and returns twice**, 0 when it's called from the current execution path and something else **via longjmp**
- **longjmp** practically signals to jump back to the point and set the new return code that **setjmp** will return.

Some sample code I tried

```
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
jmp_buf buf;
void func() {
  printf("about to jump back\n");

  longjmp(buf, 1);

  printf("unreachable\n");
}

int main() {
  // Setup jump position using buf and return 0
  if (setjmp(buf))
    printf("This should be executed because longjmp returned 1 \n");
  else {
    printf("This should be executed because setjmp returned 0\n");
    func();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

*Please, if I have misunderstood something so far feel free to correct me.*

On my actual question/problem now:

I am trying to implement **my own setjmp and longjmp with ucontext**.

Below is how I am trying to do so

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ucontext.h>

typedef struct jump_buffer {
  ucontext_t ctx;
  int is_set;
} jump_buffer_t;

jump_buffer_t buf;

int set_jumping_point(jump_buffer_t *uc_jmp_buf) {
  getcontext(&uc_jmp_buf->ctx);
  uc_jmp_buf->is_set = 0;
  return uc_jmp_buf->is_set;
}

void jump_back(jump_buffer_t *uc_jmp_buf, int value) {
  uc_jmp_buf->is_set = value;
  setcontext(&uc_jmp_buf->ctx);
}

void func() {
  printf("about to jump back\n");

  jump_back(&buf, 1);

  printf("unreachable\n");
}

int main() {
  buf.is_set = 1;
  // Setup jump position using buf and return 0
  if (set_jumping_point(&buf))
    printf("This should be executed because longjmp returned 1 \n");
  else {
    printf("This should be executed because setjmp returned 0\n");
    func();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Theoretically, my output should be

```
This should be executed because setjmp returned 0
about to jump back
This should be executed because longjmp returned 1
```

But my actual output is

```
This should be executed because setjmp returned 0
about to jump back
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

After debugging the program, I saw that the segfault occurs inside **set_jumping_point**

```
uc_jmp_buf->is_set = 0;
```

First question, why? I am assuming that since I set the context **before entering function, by struct was initialized, so even when I am going back, the struct should not be corrupted**, why the segfault?

I then tried commenting out that line but then **the function returned normally, which means that it was able to read the struct and it is not supposed to be corrupted in that case?** For the record, I am attaching the output of the code snippet with the segfaulty line commented out

```
This should be executed because longjmp returned 1
```

Can someone explain what am I missing in the bigger picture? It feels weird for that to be a segfault so I am assuming that I am misusing **ucontext**, but now sure where.

Edit : practically, **setjmp does not return properly twice**

Comment: @AndyG Thank you for your response, I do not understand how can this happen since we enter the __else__ statement, it means that we have executed the __setjmp__ function __at least once since we returned 0__ and we jump back  __inside it when we perform the setcontext from the previously saved point__. Would that be the case that I messed something up with the memory locations? Does a segfault occur only on memory related issues or could it be something else also?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that we're calling `getcontext` from a *child* function (i.e. `set_jumping_point`).

`getcontext` saves the stack frame/pointer for the function that called it. Here, this is the stack frame for `set_jumping_point`. This disappears (and becomes invalid) when `set_jumping_point` returns.

So, when we call `setcontext`, it sets the stack pointer to point to the now invalid/non-existent stack frame for `set_jumping_point`. This is UB (undefined behavior) and, in this situation, causes a segfault.

We need to save the stack context for the *caller* function (i.e. `main`) that *persists* until we call `setcontext`.

We can't do this when `set_jumping_point` is a function. We need to convert it to a macro.

In the code below, I've used a `gcc` extension to make the macro "pretty". Or, [a bit messier] we just physically cut-and-paste the code from `set_jumping_point` into `main`.

Also, we should set `is_set` *before* calling `getcontext` and we should guarantee that the compiler won't reorder the calls, so we should add a barrier.

There would be a similar issue for `setjmp` *if* we put it into a separate child function. In your example, `main` calls `setjmp` *directly*, so this is okay. If we put the `setjmp` into a subfunction (e.g. `set_jumping_point_setjmp`) and we did: `main` --> `set_jumping_point_setjmp` --> `setjmp`, it would have a similar problem.

---

Here is the corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ucontext.h>

typedef struct jump_buffer {
    ucontext_t ctx;
    int is_set;
} jump_buffer_t;

jump_buffer_t buf;

#define barrier \
    __asm__ __volatile__("" ::: "memory" )

#if 0
int
set_jumping_point(jump_buffer_t *uc_jmp_buf)
{
    getcontext(&uc_jmp_buf->ctx);
    uc_jmp_buf->is_set = 0;
    return uc_jmp_buf->is_set;
}
#else
#define set_jumping_point(_bufp) \
    ({ \
        (_bufp)->is_set = 0; \
        barrier; \
        getcontext(&(_bufp)->ctx); \
        (_bufp)->is_set; \
    })
#endif

void
jump_back(jump_buffer_t *uc_jmp_buf, int value)
{
    uc_jmp_buf->is_set = value;
    setcontext(&uc_jmp_buf->ctx);
}

void
func()
{
    printf("about to jump back\n");

    jump_back(&buf, 1);

    printf("unreachable\n");
}

int
main()
{
    buf.is_set = 1;
    // Setup jump position using buf and return 0
    if (set_jumping_point(&buf))
        printf("This should be executed because longjmp returned 1 \n");
    else {
        printf("This should be executed because setjmp returned 0\n");
        func();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is the output:

```
This should be executed because setjmp returned 0
about to jump back
This should be executed because longjmp returned 1
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several mistakes in your last set of code. Regarding the segmentation fault, the main issue is that when execution returns to the `getcontext` call within `setjumpingpoint` after calling `setcontext`, the function stack values are not the same anymore. This is because the call to `getcontext` does *not* store the entire stack contents, so `setcontext` doesn't then restore them later. This is because, as shown in Wikipedia's [setcontext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setcontext) article, we have

```cpp
typedef struct {
    ucontext_t *uc_link;
    sigset_t    uc_sigmask;
    stack_t     uc_stack;
    mcontext_t  uc_mcontext;
    ...
} ucontext_t;
```

The stack related information is stored in the `stack_t` object. As stated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32798233/11726740) to [Is the type `stack_t` no longer defined on linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20778735/11726740),

> The header defines the stack_t type as a structure that includes at least the following members:
>
> ```cpp
> void     *ss_sp       stack base or pointer
> size_t    ss_size     stack size
> int       ss_flags    flags
> ```

In particular, although the size and stack pointer are stored, the entire stack contents are not. This means that, without using a call to `makecontext` to use a different stack, the call to `setcontext` will basically just unwind the stack back to where `getcontext` was last used. Thus, it should *only* be used to return to somewhere within the current function, or to one of the parent functions going up the call stack chain.

To make this problem more explicit, although call stacks may be implemented differently depending on the machine and compiler, assume it's done as shown in the [Structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#Structure) section of Wikipedia's "Call stack" article. When `getcontext` is called within `set_jumping_point`, from the top-down we would then have

> stack pointer
> return address to main
> uc_jmp_buf pointer

After that call finishes initially, the stack would unwind back. Then the call to `func`, since it contains no parameters, would change the call stack to

> stack pointer
> return address to main

Note the uc_jmp_buf pointer has now been *overwritten* by the return address to main! The call to `jump_back` would add to the top of the stack, but not change any of the lower level values. Thus, the call to `setcontext` will, among other things, cause the stack pointer to return where it was when the `getcontext` was called, so then trying to execute the line

```cpp
uc_jmp_buf->is_set = 0;
```

will cause the code to use the return value to `main` as the pointer `uc_jmp_buf`, thus causing the segmentation fault.

---

Next, note that in your `set_jumping_point` function, the last 2 lines are

```cpp
  uc_jmp_buf->is_set = 0;
  return uc_jmp_buf->is_set;
```

The member value of `is_set` is unconditionally set to 0, and that value is returned in the next line. Thus, `set_jumping_point` will *always* return 0. There are several ways to change your code to do what you want, with I believe the simplest being to remove the `uc_jmp_buf->is_set = 0;` line and change the `buf.is_set = 1;` line to be `buf.is_set = 0;` instead. This way, the initial value returned from `set_jumping_point` will be 0, while because the value of `is_set` changes to 1 in the `jump_back` function, the second return value from `set_jumping_point` will then be 1.

One final point is that, as stated in the [setcontext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setcontext) article, regarding the `getcontext` function,

> ... the programmer must use an explicit flag variable, which must not be a register variable and must be declared volatile to avoid constant propagation or other compiler optimizations.

Thus, there's a chance that, depending on which compiler, and even which version, you're using that the program will not always work properly. As such, I suggest declaring the appropriate variable to be volatile.

---

Regarding how to fix the main issue of the segmentation fault occurring, if you're using a C++ compiler, then making the functions inline should usually work since then there's no explicit function calls, and thus changes to the stack, that would cause this problem to occur. However, the `inline` keyword is only a suggestion, not a requirement, to the compiler, although your functions should not qualify for exclusion from being inlined. Alternative methods to avoid this stack problem is to have the function code be in the `main` function itself, or to use macros, as suggested and shown in [Craig Estey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77729455/11726740).

Another option is to, such as shown in the [Example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setcontext#Example) section of Wikipedia's "setcontext" article, use `makecontext` to have a separate stack be used instead during the calls to the function.