# Why does the system keep running even though it looks like the kernel crashed?

Tags: linux-kernel, crash, centos

I've got a system in Azure size M64ls running CentOS 7. Sometimes in the terminal it shows what looks like a system crash but I can ssh into it and everything appears to be working just fine. What is going on here?

```
[305976.417482] CPU: 60 PID: 102401 Comm: threaded-ml Tainted: G    B          ------------ T 3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64 #1
[305976.424445] Hardware name: Microsoft Corporation Virtual Machine/Virtual Machine, BIOS 090007  06/02/2017
[305976.430885] Call Trace:
[305976.433264]  [<ffffffff8e37ac23>] dump_stack+0x19/0x1b
[305976.437036]  [<ffffffff8e375f86>] bad_page.part.75+0xdc/0xf9
[305976.441097]  [<ffffffff8ddc617d>] free_pages_prepare+0x1ad/0x1d0
[305976.445316]  [<ffffffff8ddc6bd4>] free_hot_cold_page+0x74/0x160
[305976.449467]  [<ffffffff8ddcbfa3>] __put_single_page+0x23/0x30
[305976.453554]  [<ffffffff8ddcbff5>] put_page+0x45/0x60
[305976.457225]  [<ffffffff8de35877>] __split_huge_page+0x387/0x880
[305976.461513]  [<ffffffff8de35de6>] split_huge_page_to_list+0x76/0xf0
[305976.465965]  [<ffffffff8de368e0>] __split_huge_page_pmd+0x1d0/0x5c0
[305976.470455]  [<ffffffff8ddef4d3>] unmap_page_range+0xc63/0xc80
[305976.474877]  [<ffffffff8ddef571>] unmap_single_vma+0x81/0xf0
[305976.479019]  [<ffffffff8ddf08f5>] zap_page_range+0xc5/0x130
[305976.483079]  [<ffffffff8e381c46>] ? rt_mutex_slowunlock+0xd6/0x120
[305976.487526]  [<ffffffff8ddeb62d>] SyS_madvise+0x49d/0xac0
[305976.491629]  [<ffffffff8e38dede>] system_call_fastpath+0x25/0x2a
[318091.991229] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
[318092.018231] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
[323176.276146] BUG: Bad page state in process ld-linux-x86-64  pfn:70d9dff
[323176.281310] page:fffffe6143677fc0 count:0 mapcount:-127 mapping:          (null) index:0x2
[323176.286928] page flags: 0x602b0e00000000()
[323176.290359] page dumped because: nonzero mapcount
[323176.293943] Modules linked in: fuse xt_owner iptable_security ext4 mbcache jbd2 xt_CHECKSUM iptable_mangle ipt_MASQUERADE nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4 iptable_nat nf_nat_ipv4 nf_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 xt_conntrack nf_conntrack ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 tun bridge stpllc ebtable_filter ebtables ip6table_filter ip6_tables devlink iptable_filter nfsv3 nfs_acl rpcsec_gss_krb5 auth_rpcgss nfsv4 dns_resolver nfs lockd grace fscache sunrpc dm_mirror dm_region_hash dm_log dm_mod joydev hv_utils ptp pps_core sg hv_balloon sb_edac iosf_mbi kvm_intel kvm irqbypass crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel lrw gf128mul glue_helper i2c_piix4 ablk_helper pcspkr cryptd binfmt_misc ip_tables xfs libcrc32c sd_mod crc_t10dif crct10dif_generic hv_storvsc scsi_transport_fc hv_netvsc hyperv_keyboard hid_hyperv scsi_tgt ata_generic pata_acpi crct10dif_pclmul ata_piix crct10dif_common hyperv_fb libata crc32c_intel floppy hv_vmbus serio_raw
[323176.352511] CPU: 43 PID: 99598 Comm: ld-linux-x86-64 Tainted: G    B          ------------ T 3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64 #1
[323176.359600] Hardware name: Microsoft Corporation Virtual Machine/Virtual Machine, BIOS 090007  06/02/2017
[323176.365912] Call Trace:
[323176.368323]  [<ffffffff8e37ac23>] dump_stack+0x19/0x1b
[323176.372191]  [<ffffffff8e375f86>] bad_page.part.75+0xdc/0xf9
[323176.376366]  [<ffffffff8ddc617d>] free_pages_prepare+0x1ad/0x1d0
[323176.380682]  [<ffffffff8ddc6bd4>] free_hot_cold_page+0x74/0x160
[323176.384934]  [<ffffffff8ddcbfa3>] __put_single_page+0x23/0x30
[323176.389101]  [<ffffffff8ddcbff5>] put_page+0x45/0x60
[323176.392883]  [<ffffffff8ddf0f70>] do_numa_page+0x230/0x250
[323176.396950]  [<ffffffff8ddf1249>] handle_pte_fault+0x2b9/0xe20
[323176.401211]  [<ffffffff8dcb09a2>] ? dequeue_signal+0x32/0x180
[323176.405416]  [<ffffffff8ddf3ecd>] handle_mm_fault+0x39d/0x9b0
[323176.409622]  [<ffffffff8e388653>] __do_page_fault+0x213/0x500
[323176.413786]  [<ffffffff8e388975>] do_page_fault+0x35/0x90
[323176.417773]  [<ffffffff8e384778>] page_fault+0x28/0x30
```

Comment: A `call trace` is not (necessarily) a *"system crash"*.  You are confusing the display of a stack dump (that was invoked on a certain condition for debugging purposes) with a (fatal) kernel panic or oops.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143924/how-to-print-the-current-thread-stack-trace-inside-the-linux-kernel  Review the kernel code that caused that output: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/mm/page_alloc.c#L639 Note the explicit calls to **pr_alert()** and **dump_stack()** in procedure **bad_page()**.  IOW this does not indicate a fatal exception.