# Is there a call stack trace in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, system, internals

I am interested in OS internals, so I would like a call Stack trace inside os linux kernel.

How could I find active, dynamic comportament of linux kernel, functions, structures ?

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/dev-tools/gdb-kernel-debugging.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print the current thread stack trace inside the Linux kernel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143924/how-to-print-the-current-thread-stack-trace-inside-the-linux-kernel)

Comment: Use `perf` tool, it may show you much more than that.