# GCC/GProf - get programmatic access to current function/stacktrace of a thread

Tags: gcc, profiling, instrumentation, gprof

I am trying to do a little wall-time profiling.

GCC adds certain runtime instrumentation code (eg for GProf) when compiling with `-pg`.

I assume it stores that information in some global or thread-local datastructure before writing it to gmon.out?

Is it possible to read that information (stacktrace) from another thread within the code itself? (If that is so, then I could add my wall-time profiling thread without having to add the instrumentation myself.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [print call stack in C or C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899870/print-call-stack-in-c-or-c)

Answer (score 2):

*gprof* does not take stack traces, and it works on CPU-time, not wall-time.
It just samples the program counter, on CPU-time, and attributes it to functions it knows about.
Its main claim to fame, compared to previous profilers, is that since PC-only ("self time") sampling is pretty useless in decent-sized apps where the call-stack is many layers deep,
it also counts how many times any function A calls any function B.
Then it tries to guess (by some pretty shaky math) how much CPU time can be charged back to the higher-level routines that are invoking the lower-level routines.

There are profilers that take stack traces on wall-time.
(CPU-time means if your app is somehow blowing time at a very low level by sleeping, I/O-ing, hanging on a semaphore, or some other blocking, you will *never see it*.)
I know of one that stack-samples on wall-time, namely [*Zoom*](http://www.rotateright.com/).
I'm told [*OProfile*](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/news/) can do it, but I can't verify it.
Same for [*DTrace*](http://dtrace.org/blogs/).

But that's just talking about the *front end*, the taking of samples.

Just as important is the *back end*, the part that *presents stuff to you*.
Typically you get "hot paths", "call graphs", "*flame graphs*", etc. etc.

Personally, I take a jaundiced view of all these spiffy toys.
What they do, they do well, no question.
But if *speedup results* are what is needed,
then the best information comes from a *small number* of stack samples,
taken at the *time you care about*, that are actually *looked at and understood*, not just summarized.

There is no summarizer that recognizes patterns better than the head of a programmer,
and any problem big enough to be worth fixing will be evident in a small number of samples.

[*Here's an example*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/927773/23771),
and [*here's another*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xPg3sRpdW1U),
and if you want to see some real math behind it, [*look here*](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/2719/1262).

Comment: That is all good information but not specific to my question. Do you know how I can use the information `-pg` generates in my own code?

Comment: @eznme: You said you're trying to do wall-time profiling. gprof doesn't do wall-time, only CPU-time. You ask if it's possible to read its information (stacktrace). gprof does not take stacktraces, only PC-samples. To do what you want, you need something else besides gprof. I've tried to explain what *does* work, in case that's useful.