# Pstack a process on OSX 10.9

Tags: linux, macos, osx-mavericks

On linux in order to view the process stack at a given time we generally use

pstack <`pid`>

I am wondering what is the equivalent of the same in osx.

thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
sudo /usr/libexec/stackshot -i -u -p <pid>
```

This appends a stack trace of all threads of the process in question to the file /Library/Logs/stackshot-syms.log . Consider to remove the file stackshot-syms.log before calling stackshot. See: stackshot(1)

Note: stackshot is no longer included with OS X 10.11 EL Capitan.
Use the lldb debugger instead:

```
echo "thread backtrace all" | lldb -p <pid>
```

lldb is part of the command line developer tools. If you don't have lldb on your machine, a popup will help with installing XCode.

Comment: how do you get stackshot?  It doesn't seem to be in my environment (El Capitan)

Comment: The difference I observe is that this "lldb" command will terminate the pid you're observing, while pstack doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

Appears "an" equivalent is the `sample` command in OS X:

`sample <pid> 0`  takes a single stacktrace sample.