# Is there a way to get the function call stack as a textual output in C or C++ application?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc

Is there a way to get the function call stack from a GNU C or C++ application?

I'm trying to investigating from where my "FunctionA" called from.

Comment: Found in related questions on the right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899870/print-call-stack-in-c-or-c?rq=1

Comment: Knowing what platform you are using is very important here because there is no standard way to do this. The answer linked by @chris gives a description of how to look at the call stack in Linux. If you are looking for how to do it on some other platform, please be specific.

Comment: It is Linux/GNU C/C++

Comment: The platform question indicated a deficiency in your question; it should have been answered by editing the question not by adding a comment - this is not a discussion forum. [GDB](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gdb/gdb_7.html) will do what you want.  In Eclipse or any other IDE that integrates GDB it is even easier.