# qDebug() print calling method

Tags: qt

I have following method for debug purposes:

```
void UeLoggedUsersInfo::uePrintLoggedUsers()
{
    qDebug() << "\n"
             << Q_FUNC_INFO
             << ":\n";
    for(int index=0; index<this->ueLoggedUsersData()->size(); index++)
    {
        qDebug() << this->ueLoggedUsersData()->at(index).constBegin().key().first
                 << this->ueLoggedUsersData()->at(index).constBegin().key().second
                 << this->ueLoggedUsersData()->at(index).constBegin().value();
    }   // for

    qDebug() << "\nEND\n";
}   // uePrintLoggedUsers
```

It traverses across some data structure and prints its mebmers values, that is all ok. But, is it possible with **`Qt` framework (without including other frameworks)** to print within this method **which method is calling it** and if it is, how?

Comment: take a look at printing the call stack: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899870/print-call-stack-in-c-or-c. There's no portable way to do it. qcrashhandler.cpp may also provide some useful information. You can find it at ${QTDIR}/Src/qtbase/stc/corelib/kernel.

Comment: @Kuba Ober the question is not C/C++, but Qt oriented, I was asking if it is possible to do it using Qt framework only.

Comment: Any answers as to whether Qt might help out there belong in the duplicate question - Qt is a C++ framework, after all. Qt provides no such functionality anyway. Normally you'd use a crash reporting framework and debug symbol files to figure such things out.

Comment: You can define a `QtMessageHandler`; install it with `qInstallMessageHandler` (see its docs).  The `QMessageLogContext` your handler receives is populated with `file`, `line` and `function` members.

Comment: @TobySpeight This does nothing to help with obtaining and decoding stack traces...

Comment: @Kuba - the linked question asks for a full backtrace; this question merely requires identification of the (immediate) calling function.  My comment wouldn't be an answer to that question.

Comment: What about providing Q_FUNC_INFO as an argument of uePrintLoggedUsers to be provided by the calling function?