# Boost stack-trace not showing function names and line numbers

Tags: c++, boost, stack-trace

I was exploring the `boost::stacktrace` by trying a simple example to print the call stack of a recursive function.

```
#include "boost/stacktrace.hpp"

int factorial(int x){
    if (x < 2) {
        std::cout << boost::stacktrace::stacktrace();
        return 1;
    }
    return x * factorial(x - 1);
}

int main(int ac, char *av[]) {
    std::cout << factorial(4);
}
```

However the output of the code does not include any information about the function name and line number:

```
 0# 0x000055A6F6B57C0F in /home/user/myapp
 1# 0x000055A6F6B57C42 in /home/user/myapp
 2# 0x000055A6F6B57C42 in /home/user/myapp
 3# 0x000055A6F6B57C42 in /home/user/myapp
 4# 0x000055A6F6B57C9D in /home/user/myapp
 5# __libc_start_main in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
 6# 0x000055A6F6B57AEA in /home/user/myapp
```

This is in contrast with the sample output from the boost website:
(copied from https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/stacktrace/getting_started.html#stacktrace.getting_started.how_to_print_current_call_stack)

```
0# bar(int) at /path/to/source/file.cpp:70
1# bar(int) at /path/to/source/file.cpp:70
2# bar(int) at /path/to/source/file.cpp:70
3# bar(int) at /path/to/source/file.cpp:70
4# main at /path/to/main.cpp:93
5# __libc_start_main in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
6# _start
```

Why don't I see the source line numbers and function names in the stack-trace output?

I have enabled debugging information in my project-level `CMakeList.txt`:

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
```

I can also see the symbols are present when demangling the binary file:

```
nm -an myapp | c++filt | grep factorial

0000000000000f40 t _GLOBAL__sub_I__Z9factoriali
00000000000010f0 T factorial(int)
```

Comment: Do you compile with debug information enabled?

Comment: @tkausl yes, I added set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug) in my cmake file

Comment: Also does your build use `strip`? Can your debugger see symbols in the executable?

Comment: @PaulFloyd, I can see the symbols in my debugger and also when I run : nm -an myapp | c++filt and function names are present.

Comment: Show complete command lines used to compile and link.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin g++ -g /home/user/myapp.cpp  -ldl

Comment: Hello @motam79 , are you solve it to see function name and line number? I am facing same problem in MSVC on WIndows.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to do a few things (this is for Linux):

1. Make sure that debug info is enabled: e.g., `-g`
2. Link against libdl: `-ldl`
3. Define one of the necessary macros (to get line numbers): e.g., `-DBOOST_STACKTRACE_USE_ADDR2LINE`

All this info is provided here:

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/stacktrace/configuration_and_build.html

Comment: Does boost stacktrace use dynsym or symtab section? I ask because backtrace_symbols uses dynsym which we don't fill.

Answer (score 17):

I do not have enough reputation to comment, so I'll extend jordi's answer here:

1. Make sure that debug info is enabled: e.g., -g
2. Link against libdl: -ldl
3. Define one of the necessary macros (to get line numbers): e.g., -DBOOST_STACKTRACE_USE_ADDR2LINE
4. **Compile and link with -no-pie and -fno-pie options.**

Comment: The -no-pie and -fno-pie give me function names now, still no line numbers though.

Comment: @Owl see: stackoverflow.com/a/71027489/895245 that is working now. This answer was working on Boost 1.67 Ubuntu 19.10, but not anymore on Boost 1.74 Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked for me, I am compiling with g++ :

- Compile with -g -ggdb -no-pie -fno-pie -rdynamic
- define macro -DBOOST_STACKTRACE_USE_ADDR2LINE
- Link against libdl -libl and -no-pie -fno-pie

**Edit** : in my case rdynamic was the missing bit to allow me to have unmagled function names and line numbers

Comment: As most of the information in this answer is repeating earlier answers, it would help to highlight the options you added, especially if you could explain why you made the additions.

Comment: Fair enough, -rdynamic was the key in my case.

Comment: To set -rdynamic using cmake add the line `set_property(TARGET your_target PROPERTY ENABLE_EXPORTS ON)`

Comment: In case of `-rdynamic` and CMake, from my experiments it seems it must be added to linker rather than compiler options.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
g++ -g backtrace.cpp -o bb -lboost_stacktrace_backtrace -D BOOST_STACKTRACE_LINK
```

**-D BOOST_STACKTRACE_LINK** was the missing option that solved the problem for me.

Comment: Tested on boost 1.74, Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 0):

If you use cmake this worked for me on linux machine

```
add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_compile_definitions(main PRIVATE BOOST_STACKTRACE_USE_ADDR2LINE)
target_compile_options(main PRIVATE "-g;-fno-inline")
target_link_options(main PRIVATE "-no-pie")
target_link_libraries(main ${Boost_LIBRARIES}  dl)
```

see [this example](https://github.com/jschueller/boost-stacktrace-example/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt)