# How to use <stacktrace> in GCC trunk?

Tags: c++, libstdc++, c++23, compiler-explorer

From https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/3acb929cc0beb79e6f4005eb22ee88b45e1cbc1d commit, C++ standard header `<stacktrace>` exists things such as `std::stacktrace_entry` but is not declared since `_GLIBCXX_HAVE_STACKTRACE` is not defined neither.

I have tried this on https://godbolt.org/z/b9TvEMYnh but linker error is emitted once I have added the argument `-lstd++_libbacktrace` (ofc, it was not found)

```cpp
#include <stacktrace> // header found

int main() {
  // can't use features like 'std::stacktrace_entry' and 'std::stacktrace'
}
```

What does this message mean from the commit description? :

> For now, the new library is only built if --enable-libstdcxx-backtrace=yes is used.

Comment: This is now fixed on Compiler Explorer - you still need to link against stdc++_backtrace though - https://godbolt.org/z/We4T8f4q8

Comment: @MattGodbolt Unfortunately this seems not to work anymore.

Comment: @MattGodbolt: No it [isn't](https://godbolt.org/z/qM8119Y8b).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Part of building GCC from source is to run the `configure` shell script and pass it a bunch of arguments to tell it how to behave.  That commit message is telling you that in order to enable this feature, you must add the following configure argument:

```
--enable-libstdcxx-backtrace=yes
```