# How can I generate a C++23 stacktrace with GCC 12.1?

Tags: c++, linux, g++, c++23

In the [release notes](https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/gcc-12/changes.html) for GCC12, under the section "*Runtime Library (libstdc++)*", it says:

> Improved experimental C++23 support, including: [...] <stacktrace> (not built by default, requires linking to an extra library).

What library do I need to link against to use [`<stacktrace>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/stacktrace)? I'm on an x86 Linux
system, if that matters.

Comment: `-lbacktrace` maybe?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70765285/how-to-use-stacktrace-in-gcc-trunk

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to link with `-lstdc++_libbacktrace` ([as documented here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.3.0/libstdc++/manual/manual/using.html#manual.intro.using.flags)). Note that since GCC14, you should use `-lstdc++exp` instead ([as documented here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using.html#manual.intro.using.flags)).

In order for this to work, gcc needs to have been configured with `--enable-libstdcxx-backtrace`.