# How to retrieve a complete C++ stack trace on GCC with <stacktrace> standard library?

Tags: c++, debugging, gcc, stack-trace

When I try to retrieve a stack trace from GCC I **always** have the same result. I doesn't depend on where it has been called because the software I am working on is giving me exactly the same stack.

### Main.cpp

```cpp
#include <stacktrace>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << std::stacktrace::current() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

### Compilation

```
$ g++ -g3 -std=c++23 Main.cpp -lstdc++_libbacktrace
```

### Result

```
0#      at :32764
1#      at :32764
2#      at :32764
3#      at :32764
4#
```

### Setup

I am running arch linux with this version of GCC:

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: /build/gcc/src/gcc/configure --enable-languages=ada,c,c++,d,fortran,go,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-bootstrap --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=https://bugs.archlinux.org/ --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-cet=auto --enable-checking=release --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-default-pie --enable-default-ssp --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-libstdcxx-backtrace --enable-link-serialization=1 --enable-linker-build-id --enable-lto --enable-multilib --enable-plugin --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --disable-libssp --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-werror
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 13.2.1 20230801 (GCC)
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Also, you should be using `-llstdc++exp` for more recent version of GCC. See https://godbolt.org/z/nKTe31Eb1

Comment: @JanSchultke Thank you for your time, could you please explain me what is stdc++exp ? I don't find materials on the internet..
I could reproduce it on another computer with the same specs (GCC 13.2, arch linux)

Comment: @JanSchultke https://godbolt.org/z/Md5GGnrMx

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72342952/5740428

Comment: @JanSchultke It must not work with GCC 13.2.1, thank you