# c++23 building with <stacktrace> library

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, stack-trace, c++23

I'm trying to use "stacktrace" library from my c++ project.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/stacktrace

I'm using GCC 13 and CPP standard 23.

In my cmake file, I am adding
`target_link_libraries([Target] stdc++_libbacktrace)`

If I compile, I get the following error.

```
compile_utils.cpp:10:34: error: ‘std::stacktrace’ has not been declared
   10 |     const auto stacktrace = std::stacktrace::current();
```

Also I tried to enable the following flag via
`set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} --enable-libstdcxx-backtrace")`
But then I get the following cmake build error
`cc1plus: error: unknown pass libstdcxx-backtrace specified in ‘-fenable’`

How can I resolve the above errors?

Thank  you very much!

// Usage

```
#include <stacktrace>

void test()
{
    const auto stacktrace = std::stacktrace::current();
    const auto strStackTrace = stacktrace.to_string();    
}
```

// Just in case, using `"Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS"`

// Just in case, tried `target_link_libraries([Target] stdc++exp)` too but no luck

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.2.0/libstdc++/manual/manual/using.html#manual.intro.using.flags

Comment: You included the stacktrace header right?

Comment: @kiner_shah yep, added code snippet above

Comment: As per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70765285/4688321), your compiler needs to be built with that enable-libstdcxx-backtrace flag. Note your compiler, not the program.

Comment: @kiner_shah ah... compiler... ugh.. I saw that post but didn't read its compiler build flag..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this got answered (and I'd love to see how you solved it if it did) But it appears if you have installed G++13 through just an apt-get install g++-13, this doesn't have stacktrace enabled:

<bits/c++config.h>

```
/* Define if the <stacktrace> header is supported. */
/* #undef _GLIBCXX_HAVE_STACKTRACE */
```

Unless there's some other solution, it appears the default build doesn't support stacktrace. I would note that I am doing this through an arm-ubuntu23.04 image, and it may also be an arm thing, I would defer to someone who may know a bit more about th