# Problems adding a breakpoint with commands from command line with ex command

Tags: gdb

I try to start a program with gdb from commands line, then immediately add a breakpoint with commands, then run:

gdb -q -ex 'set pagination off' -ex 'break XOpenDisplay' -ex 'commands' -ex 'silent' -ex 'info locals' -ex 'bt full' -ex 'cont' -ex 'end'  -ex 'r' ./myprogram

The program gets stuck after the "commands" prompting me to enter commands via keyboard then enter "end".

Did I forget something?

Regards

Update:

I added a .gdbinit with the following content:

```
gdb -q -ex breakXOpenDisplayRun


define breakXOpenDisplayRun
set pagination off
break XOpenDisplay
commands
  silent
  info locals
  bt full
  cont
end
run
end
```

gdb -q -ex breakXOpenDisplayRun ./myapp

When the program encounters the breakpoint the first time it stops there prompting a user input which should not happen. After the first cont it works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to gdb mailing list Andrew Burgess. This is a bug that has been fixed in gdb 11. For versions before that, using a separate source worked for me:

gdb -q -ex 'source breakXOpenDisplayRun.gdb' ./myapp

Answer (score 1):

The `-ex` expects a *complete* command, and in case of `commands` the complete command is

```
commands
  silent
  info locals
  bt full
  cont
end
```

While you *can* enter multi-line command at the shell prompt, doing so is exceedingly awkward, and you'll be better off putting all of the desired commands into a temporary command file. Something like this should work:

```
cat > /tmp/gdb.$$ <<"EOF" && gdb -x /tmp/gdb.$$ ./myprogram && rm -f /tmp/gdb.$$
set pagination off
break XOpenDisplay'
commands
  silent
  info locals
  bt full
  cont
end
run
EOF
```

Comment: Update in the original question. I put the commands into a function in .gdbinit but it gets stuck when it first encounters the breakpoint.

Comment: With "stuck" I mean it stops there and prompts me for input although  it should just execute info locals and bt full and continue. When I enter cont then it continues as it should and further encounters with the breakpoint are silent.

Comment: I don't think `commands` on `-ex` works even if you inject newlines, e.g.: `gdb -nh -batch -ex 'b f' -ex "$(printf 'commands\nbt\ncontinue\nend')" -ex r hello.out` does not hit function `f` multiple times as expected. Same `printf` to file + `-x` works however. GDB 12.0.90. I would also make the temporary file with `mktemp`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181937/how-create-a-temporary-file-in-shell-script