# cannot get backtrace from stack address of pthread_attr_getstack

Tags: c++, linux, backtrace

i want to get all thread backtrace, but cannot get any api to do it directly.
so i find an api pthread_attr_getstack can get the stack address of thread.
but i do not know how to get backtrace from the stack address of the  pthread_attr_getstack

I searched all the questions and answers on this website and found no relevant answers.

Comment: `pthread_attr_getstack` isn't the right tool for this job. [Here's a list and rundown of several tools that will get what you want](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3899870/4581301). I recommend trying out, and maybe asking some questions about, some of them.

Comment: I've seen this Q&A. I want to get the backtrace of all threads, not just the current thread.