# Finding address of a local variable in C with GDB

Tags: c, gdb

Say I have some C code which goes along the lines of:

```
void fun_1(unsigned int *age)
```

[...]

```
int main() {

    unsigned int age[24];
}
```

In GDB, how can I find the address of age?

Comment: "Finding address of function" - `age` is not a function in your code snippet.

Comment: Which age? Wouldn't `p &age` work after you enter the any of the functions? Both have `age`.

Comment: Plz, there are a lot of sites about simple gdb's commands out there. Try google before post at SO. ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_109.html

Comment: Are you interested in the address of the local variable `age`, which just a pointer, or the address that `age` points to?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the exact address of variable Buf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462915/find-the-exact-address-of-variable-buf)

Answer (score 15):

Finding address is as simple as:

```
p &age
```

Answer (score 7):

Both `age`s are not the same in case if you are not aware. One is local in `main` and another is local to `fun_1()`. So unless you pass the address of `age` in `main` to `fun_1()` they are not going to have the same address. Just set a break point in main and see the address of age.

```
(gdb) break main
(gdb) p &age
.....
(gdb) break fun_1
(gdb) p &age
.....
```