# How to use GDB to find what function a memory address corresponds to

Tags: c++, gdb

I am using google's heap checker to track down a memory leak.  It gives me a stack trace such as:

```
Leak of 21 bytes in 1 objects allocated from:                                                                                                                                                               
    @ 0xf6088241                                                                                                                                                                                               
    @ 0xf60890d2                                                                                                                                                                                               
    @ 0xf6089246                                                                                                                                                                                               
    @ 0x8054781                                                                                                                                                                                                
    @ 0x8054862                                                                                                                                                                                                
    @ 0xf684ee76                                                                                                                                                                                               
    @ 0xf684f343                                                                                                                                                                                               
    @ 0x804be4c                                                                                                                                                                                                
    @ 0x80544f6                                                                                                                                                                                                
    @ 0xf5e52bb6                                                                                                                                                                                               
    @ 0x804b101
```

How do I determine what functions/lines of code these memory addresses correspond to?

Comment: I am surprised Google's heap checker does not do this conversion for you.  Are you sure you compiled with "-g"?  (Also, take a look at the [addr2line command](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/addr2line.html))

Comment: Any symbol type question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762628/gdb-getting-a-symbol-name-from-a-memory-address

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use `info symbol` gdb command. [16 Examining the Symbol Table](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Symbols.html).

```
info symbol addr
```

Print the name of a symbol which is stored at the address addr. If no symbol is stored exactly at addr, gdb prints the nearest symbol and an offset from it:

```
(gdb) info symbol 0x54320
_initialize_vx + 396 in section .text
```

This is the opposite of the info address command. You can use it to find out the name of a variable or a function given its address.

For dynamically linked executables, the name of executable or shared library containing the symbol is also printed:

```
(gdb) info symbol 0x400225
_start + 5 in section .text of /tmp/a.out
(gdb) info symbol 0x2aaaac2811cf
__read_nocancel + 6 in section .text of /usr/lib64/libc.so.6
```

Comment: So, after I got a list of info commands, and figured out that `info address` doesn't lookup address, turned out there's also a `info symbol` command, which doesn't query a symbol.

Answer (score 14):

The original question asked how to do this in GDB:

```
# NOT what you want; note the lack of '*':
(gdb) info symbol 0xfde09edc
blah() + 388 in section .text of /tmp/libblah.so

# IS what you want; note the presence of '*':
(gdb) info line *0xfde09edc
Line 91 of "blah.cc"
   starts at address 0xfde09ebc <blah()+356>
   and ends at 0xfde09ee4 <blah()+396>
```

The `*` is necessary for `info line` and shouldn't be used for `info symbol`.

You can also use the `disassemble` command with its `/m` flag:

```
(gdb) disassemble /m 0xfde09edc
```

... though it's rather verbose and `info line` gives exactly what was requested.

Comment: Please note that `/m` modifier is deprecated in favor of `/s` (appeared in gdb 7.11). Anyway, you can use much less verbose output of `x/i 0xfde09edc` instead of disassembling the whole function.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your binary has debug information `g++ -g` you may be able to use `x/` to get the info, I know that works for vtables.

`x/<num>xw` to print `<num>` hex words of memory, and gdb will annotate the left side with information about what's at the address.