# Find all variables pointing to an address in gdb

Tags: c++, debugging, crash, gdb, coredump

For context, my particular case is the following: I got a segfault and am analyzing the core; the stack trace shows the program called exit but crashed before completing it, within some vector's d'tor; I can get the address of the vector, but I am not familiar with the code and I don't know what variable it corresponds to; I would like to find out what variables are pointing to this vector to inspect related code. Any suggestions?

Comment: If the operating system fits: Try valgrind

Comment: What do you mean by saying "variables are pointing to this vector". Do you mean the pointer variable that holds the vector object address?

Comment: @AlexeyTeplyakov: which are the C++ variables whose current value is that vector

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the symbol name for a memory address in GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762628/how-to-get-the-symbol-name-for-a-memory-address-in-gdb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can get the address of the vector... I would like to find out what
>   variables are pointing to this vector

Having the address of some variable you can use `info symbol` command to print the name of a variable like this:

```
(gdb) info symbol 0x4005BDC
```

See [Examining the Symbol Table](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Symbols.html) in gdb documentation.

Comment: Unfortunately this method doesn't work with local (automatic) variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a breakpoint right before the crash and print all the variables within the std::vector.

```
print *(your_vector._M_impl._M_start)@your_vector.size()
```

for example:

with `std::vector<int> vec(3);` you would write `print *(vec._M_impl._M_start)@3`