# GDB Python API: Getting symbol name from address

Tags: gdb

In GDB shell I can get symbol name from address like this:

```
(gdb) info symbol 0x405ece
top::test_thread() in section .text of test_procs
```

How can I do the same using Python GDB API (https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Python-API.html)? Is it possible at all?

Comment: From outside gdb see [debugging - How to get the symbol name for a memory address in GDB? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762628/how-to-get-the-symbol-name-for-a-memory-address-in-gdb) ■ Reverse question: [Get address of a global symbol from symbol name with GDB Python API - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54070055/get-address-of-a-global-symbol-from-symbol-name-with-gdb-python-api?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work (untested):

```
block = gdb.block_for_pc(0x405ece)
while block and not block.function:
  block = block.superblock

print block.function.print_name
```

Comment: It looks like iteration is not required in my case, since I know in advance that pointer holds valid address of function or method

Comment: Hmm.. also it seems that documentation is not correct. Instead of returning None for invalid address, it throws run-time exception

Comment: This does not work for things like `_start` symbol. (because it doesn't have debugging information?