# Is there a gdb python API for 'info symbol'?

Tags: python, gdb, gdb-python

I'm trying to use `info symbol $frameptr` but in a gdb script. Is there an equivalent in the gdb python API?

Comment: Worst case you can parse the output with Python (`gdb.execute(..., to_string=True)`), or use GDB/MI. ■ Probably somewhere near [Symbol Tables In Python (Debugging with GDB)](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Symbol-Tables-In-Python.html#Symbol-Tables-In-Python)

Comment: There's [GDB Python API: Getting symbol name from address - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47916564/gdb-python-api-getting-symbol-name-from-address?noredirect=1&lq=1) but I'm not sure if it supports the frame pointer or similar.